# Error at execl: No such file or directory

Tags: c, exec

This is an example that our professor gave us for execl(). There are 2 files in a folder, com1.c looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello...");
    fflush(stdout);
    execlp("com2","com2",(char*)NULL);
    perror("err at execl");
    return 1;
}
```

and com2.c looks like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    write(1, "...you unicorn ;)",13);
    return 0;
}
```

At runtime it gives me this message:
`hello...err at execl: No such file or directory`

How can I get "hello...... you unicorn ;" ?
Anticipated thanks.

Comment: Did you build an executable named `com2` and put it in a directory in PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the directory containing `com2` is in your `PATH` environment variable.

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

where `/path/to/directory` is the directory where you put `com2`.

Comment: Is there a way for com2.c to overlay com1.c without making changes to PATH? com1.c and com2.c are in the same directory, from what I understood that means I don't have to change PATH

Comment: It depends on the operating system.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022934/how-do-i-get-the-executing-programs-directory-in-c-using-a-plataform-independen

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what OS you're running ... but, in general, the directory that contains the program you wish to exec should be in your $PATH:

> https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp
>
> The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions
> of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified
> filename does not contain a slash (/) character. The file is sought in
> the colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the PATH
> environment variable.
>
> If this variable isn't defined, the path list
> defaults to the current directory followed by the list of directories
> returned by confstr(_CS_PATH). (This [confstr(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/confstr) call typically returns
> the value "/bin:/usr/bin".) If the specified filename includes a slash
> character, then PATH is ignored, and the file at the specified
> pathname is executed.

Note:

> On some other systems, the default path (used when the environment
> does not contain the variable PATH) has the current working directory
> listed after /bin and /usr/bin, as an anti-Trojan-horse measure. Linux
> uses here the traditional "current directory first" default path.