# MySQL - SELECT * plus another field syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

With MySQL, I seem to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT *, name
FROM Customers
```

But I get a syntax error if I reverse the order:

```
SELECT name, *
FROM Customers
```

I have tried giving the `name` an alias and that doesn't help. I know I could do this with a join on the same table, but I'm hoping that there is a simple syntax that will allow this to work without a self-join. Is this possible with another syntax or am I stuck with only being able to add additional query result fields after instead of before selecting all with an asterisk (*)?

Comment: "All columns" pattern allows to select additional columns/expressions. But it cannot be an addition. *but I'm hoping that there is a simple syntax that will allow this to work without a self-join* Do not use asterisk, list all column names one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL tends to be more lenient that other relational database engines, but even that isn't something I'd rely on. From [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) (emphasis mine):

> Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list **may** produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference

The reliable and portable alternative would be:

```
SELECT name, Customers.*
FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is a good idea to qualify all column references -- even `*`.

So, this works in either order:

```
select name, c.*
from Customers c;
```

Or better yet:

```
select c.name as new_name, c.*
from Customers c;
```

Note:  You should probably give `name` as different alias so there are not duplicate column names.

The one exception is when you are using the `USING` clause for a `JOIN`.  Then `*` makes sense.  When using `*` with `USING`, the `JOIN` key are not repeated in the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: You can reference the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022934/how-do-i-get-the-executing-programs-directory-in-c-using-a-plataform-independen): **Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference**

Comment: *The one exception is when you are using the `USING` clause for a `JOIN`. Then `*` makes sense.* Can you explain this phrase in details? why so? it looks strange..

Comment: @Akina In `USING` you just list columns that are common to both tables in the join, so it doesn't make sense to qualify them with table prefixes. `USING (x)` is equivalent to `ON tbl1.x = tbl2.x`

Comment: @Barmar You are wrong. Test `SELECT col, t1.col, t2.col FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING (col);`, or RIGHT JOIN. You'll see that qualified `tablename.name` is critical. The same about asterisk - without qualification you cannot distinguish does this output row has source parts in both tables or in left table only.

Comment: OUTER JOIN is an exception because the column can have different values when there's no match.