# CreateProcess from a process started from a `cmd` file

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm attempting to launch a process from a different process. The mechanism in which this is achieved is not subject to change. Both the launcher and the original process are located in `C:\dir`.

I'm starting my launcher from a `cmd` file. The `cmd` file itself is located somewhere else, and in order for it to find the launcher executable, I'm setting the `PATH` variable:

```
set PATH=C:\dir;%PATH%;
launcher.exe
```

The launcher starts the child process with the following code:

```
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
  startupInfo.cb               = sizeof (STARTUPINFO);
  startupInfo.lpReserved       = 0;
  startupInfo.lpDesktop        = NULL;
  startupInfo.lpTitle          = NULL;
  startupInfo.dwX              = 0;
  startupInfo.dwY              = 0;
  startupInfo.dwXSize          = 0;
  startupInfo.dwYSize          = 0;
  startupInfo.dwXCountChars    = 0;
  startupInfo.dwYCountChars    = 0;
  startupInfo.dwFillAttribute  = 0;
  startupInfo.dwFlags          = _showInForeground ? STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW : 0;
  startupInfo.wShowWindow      = _showInForeground ? 1 : 0;
  startupInfo.cbReserved2      = 0;
  startupInfo.lpReserved2      = 0;

  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

  BOOL retVal = CreateProcess("child.exe", "", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                    _showInForeground ? (CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE) : CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
                    NULL, NULL, &startupInfo,&processInfo);
```

It returns `0` and last error is `2`, which is `File not found`.

If it helps, `GetCurrentDirectory` returns the directory where the `cmd` is located, not `C:\dir`. I'm guessing `CreateProcess` can't find `child.exe` because PATH is not available to it.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

**EDIT: Some good comments with answers (as comments are sometimes overlooked):**

**Suggestion: set statupInfo.lpDirectory to "c:\dir"**

Answer: can't. I'm starting from the cmd because the directory may change.

Comment: set statupInfo.lpDirectory to "c:\\dir"

Comment: @Lucian can't. I'm starting from the `cmd` because the directory may change.

Comment: Why mess with the PATH variable at all ? If the cmd file knows the location of the executable to be launched, why not pass the path to the executable as a parameter to your launcher on the command line ? `launcher.exe c:\dir\child.exe`

Comment: @WaffleSouffle this is just one of many `cmd` files generated by a legacy tool which is not subject to change.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore. The launcher process can get its own folder and use that. There is no need to change the path variable or change the working dir.

Comment: @Deanna "GetCurrentDirectory returns the directory where the cmd is located, not C:\dir".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That's not what I said. Use `GetModuleFileName()` to get the exe path itself. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1528298/588306) for more information.

Comment: @Deanna ok perhaps I over simplified. Or misinformed. The two aren't *necessarily* in the same directory. They are in directories set in PATH by the script. molbdnilo's answer is perfect because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN, CreateProcess actually *does* search PATH, but only if `lpApplicationName` is `NULL` and the executable is the first token in `lpCommandLine`.
In other words it *should* work if you call `CreateProcess(NULL, "child.exe", ...`

I haven't tried it though, so YMMV and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The launcher process can get its own path using `GetModuleFileName()` that it can use to create the full path to the 2nd executable. There is no need to change the Path environment variable or change the working directoy.

Comment: The two aren't necessarily in the same directory. They are in directories set in PATH by the script.

Comment: You said they were "Both the launcher and the original process are located in C:\dir"