# How to Get the Filename of the Currently Running Executable in C++

Tags: c++, filenames

I want to get the full path of the current process.

I use `_getcwd` to get the current working directory. But it not includes file name.

How can I get file name like: `filename.exe`?

Comment: It's typically the 0-th argument to command line apps.

Comment: try arg 0 , it should be there

Comment: this feed will provide help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On windows you can use:

```
TCHAR szExeFileName[MAX_PATH]; 
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);
```

szExeFileName will contain full path + executable name

[edit]

For more portable solution use `argv[0]` or some other platform specific code. You can find such aproach here: https://github.com/mirror/boost/blob/master/libs/log/src/process_name.cpp.

Comment: This is not portable

Comment: @sancelot there is no portable code for doing this, OP in one of his/her comments asked for win32 platform and so this answer. Also under windows you dont have access to argv[0] in all application types. btw. I have added some hints for making this in portable way.

Answer (score 33):

`argv[0]` of your main function is your filename.

A simple code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //access argv[0] here
}
```

If you cannot access/change code in main(), you can do something like this:

```
std::string executable_name()
{
#if defined(PLATFORM_POSIX) || defined(__linux__) //check defines for your setup

    std::string sp;
    std::ifstream("/proc/self/comm") >> sp;
    return sp;

#elif defined(_WIN32)

    char buf[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameA(nullptr, buf, MAX_PATH);
    return buf;

#else

    static_assert(false, "unrecognized platform");

#endif
}
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name that the user used to call your program. If the user used a symlink, `argv[0]` is the symlink, not the binary itself.

Comment: You can extract the file name from argv[0] using something like this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1962/#msg7180

Comment: I use int WINAPI WinMain() show how can i do it by this way

Comment: how can I do the same for a dll file ?

Answer (score 9):

On Linux, the filename of your binary is the destination of a symlink at `/proc/self/exe`. You can use the `readlink` system call to find the destination of a symlink.

Note that this tells you the actual location on disk where the binary is stored, not simply the command the user used to start your program.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı, I would imagine [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) would do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a cross-platform way using boost (https://www.boost.org/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dll.hpp>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

    std::cout << "hello world, this is [" << boost::dll::program_location().filename().string() << "]" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "or [" << boost::dll::program_location().string() << "] if you're not into the whole brevity thing." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

compiled via

```
g++ -o hello_world hello_world.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -ldl
```

results in the output

```
hello world, this is [hello_world]
or [/home/gjvc/tmp/hello_world] if you're not into the whole brevity thing.
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, the name of your *executable* is contained in argv[0]. If you need that, you could:

```
cout << argv[0] << endl;
```

If you need the name of a *source file* of the executable, C++ has a predefined macro you can use:

```
cout << __FILE__ << endl;
```

[Go to here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) and scroll to "Predefined macro names"

Answer (score 3):

You can use program_invocation_name from errno.h

https://linux.die.net/man/3/program_invocation_short_name

Answer (score 2):

In Linux (POSIX?) there is an enviroment variable called `_` that contains the current process.

```
$ echo $_
echo
```

In C++

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* getenv */
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << getenv("_") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

compile

```
$ c++ a.cpp -o a.out
$ ./a.out
```

prints `./a.out` (or whatever is the executed line, including path).

This has certain advantages over the other approaches, it can be read globally (not passing `argv[0]`) and doesn't need file handling.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on my linux box. It prints the pid of and path to the shell. not the name of the current process. However, if I then call another prorgram via system, that child process will have the correct name. This seems to work slightly differently for different variants of unix as well.

Comment: @TomTanner, it may depend on the shell also. For example I get that the variable can contain the relative path of the executing line. For example `tmp/a.out` if I run it from a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually get the executable file name from `argv[0]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 printf("Running: %s\n", argv[0]);
 return 0;
}
```

Indeed, there are ways for an application to `execl()` another application (or another similar function) and override this argument. It still is unconventional for the system to change it for that sort of application.

Comment: wrong order of argc and argv, and I already gave the answer :)

Comment: Re *You can always get the executable file name from argv[0]* : Not always. It's convention to invoke `execl` with `argv[0]` set to the program name. It is also a hackable convention. Making argv[0] null is somewhat standard in secure environments.

Comment: Thanks to both. I fixed a few things in my answer, though there isn't much to worry about now.