# Get full directory of application Windows

Tags: c++, file, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable)

I have an application on C++, how can I get my full directory (where .exe file of this application exists)?

Edit: OS - Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows:

```
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, ARRAYSIZE(path));
```

Linux:

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
readlink("/proc/self/exe", buffer, MAX_PATH);
```

Comment: Thanks @Barter, I have a Windows but it returns path with .exe name, how can i cut this exe name from end of the path?

Comment: All you need to do is find last \ and put NULL in that place. Or using [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's no good cross-platform solution for this, however, you can do this on all major platforms:

- on Linux: read the `/proc/self/exe` special file

---

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
ssize_t len;
if ((len = readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, bufsize)) != -1) {
    // buf contains the path
} else {
    // error
}
```

- on Mac OS X: use the `_NSGetExecutablePath()` function (from `man 3 dyld`)

---

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

uint32_t size = PATH_MAX;
char buf[PATH_MAX];
if (_NSGetExecutablePath(buf, &size) != -1) {
    // buf now contains the path
} else {
    // error
}
```

- on Windows: call `GetModuleFileName()` with `NULL` as the handle.

---

```
#include <windows.h>

char buffer[1024];
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 0) {
    // buffer contains the path
} else {
    // error
}
```