# Cross platform way for a simple binary (executable) self check

Tags: c, security, cross-platform

So the question is: How it is possible to realize a simple self-checking executable in a cross platform way using standard C libraries?

Here I am seeking for the **technique**, not for a particular check method (like CRC or hash codes), but the technique may contain elements more tailored towards certain methods (see below for example).

The aim is to provide means to indicate that the binary is probably broken most probably for some virus' action or transmission failure, and may not be capable to execute as it is supposed to. It is not intended to guard against intentional tamper targeting especially the executable in question.

It should be reasonably cross platform. Ideally it should use only standard C libraries, but methods which are capable to run on most used systems (Linux variants, Android, Mac OS, Windows) may be applicable too if it's not achieved by extraneous conditional compilation.

My current idea would be simply opening the binary for reading only using standard file I/O, using the first parameter (argv) passed to the program which is the launched executable's name, and apply a check algorithm on that which is independent of the position of some check code. (Simple checksum meets this requirement by providing an otherwise unused position for making the sum of the complete binary evaluating to zero. CRC algorithms may also be utilized, but it is not so trivial to insert a suitable value in an arbitrary point of the binary)

Even this technique [could fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable) though, although maybe the information in argv[0] is sufficient to always reliably find the binary of the executable itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should insert a static character buffer in your code where you want to store the CRC of your binary file. You should surrond your buffer with some known MAGIC sequence so that you will identify it while scanning the binary... this way you can skip the CRC data in the binary so that your CRC check does not depend on it.

Comment: Well, this is rather for check method. I thought of this too, but it would unnecessarily complicate the _end result_ if the particular algorithm is capable to live without it otherwise. Of course it makes generation a lot easier (compared to say brute-forcing a value for a 32bit CRC in a 200K binary), but once the binary is ready having a bunch of sequences in it to detect the CRC, and code to process them is a lot uglier than simply having a binary which simply gives a pre-set CRC. So I would rather avoid once I get to be able to reasonably do this check as the question primarily asks.