# Getting module name and process name in LINUX C++

Tags: c++, linux, process, module

I have a shared library with 2 methods (among others of course) that i want to port to linux:

GetProcessName() - Should get the executable name or path (either would do)
GetModuleName()  - Should return the name of the module that's running the code (either dll or exe).

In a windows environment I use [**GetModuleFileName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a different variation for both methods.

I've seen plenty of solutions for getting the process name, but most of them seem kinda Hacky.
And I haven't found a solution for getting the module name.

Is there a similar function in linux ?
How can I implement them ?

Comment: For the process there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1528493/63743).  I don't think there is an equivalent of the running libs or at least one that would not be seriously "hacky".

Comment: I guess I can make do with a "hacky" solution for the running module/library if it's the only way, but i haven't found any solution for that yet.

Comment: @MSalters: Isn't the duplicate less specific than this question? While the answer to that question (how to get path to an executable/library file) is no doubt part of solution to this question, the other question and it's answer do not address the question of how to get the  path to the library that is **currently executing**. Would an answer to that question be relevant to the duplicate question?

Comment: @user2079303: It's indeed less specific: it can get any library, not just the one currently executing. You just need an address, which is the current IP.

Comment: @MSalters: And what's the simplest, non compiler/arch specific way (as long as it works on linux) to get the current IP? It doesn't seem trivial to me and I can't find such question using the search feature. Should I create a new question for that?

Comment: @user2079303: Ehm, the current Instruction Pointer is a register on all Linux architectures I'm aware of. I didn't mean IP as in 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @MSalters: I understood what you meant. My question is, how to read the register in c++ i.e. how to get the current value of the instruction pointer. Preferably in a way that doesn't depend on compiler or cpu architechture.

Comment: No compiler-independent way (ISO C++ does not assume an IP register exists), GCC has `__builtin_return_address(0)` (put this in a non-inlined helper function)

Comment: @MSalters __builtin_return_address(0) still wont get me the module name.

Comment: @MSalters This long debate just shows it's not answered anywhere. should be reopened so someone can answer it for the rest of the world to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's some confusion, here are the two steps to get the "module" data for the current function.

1. Get the current function, either by the IP register or by calling a small function that just returns  `__builtin_return_address(0)`. Yet another method is to just take `&foo` inside `foo()`.
2. Call `dladdr`, passing the address of the current function.

Comment: Hi! I just wanted a quick clarification if I choose to do it this way. Is `dli_fbase` specifically going to represent the module?

Comment: @minhanhb: I don't understand the question. `dli_fbase` *is* the base address where the module is loaded. It's *not* a handle like `dlopen` returns.