# Reading from a .txt file with an unspecified name but with a known directory c++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have built a program in c++ whitch checks how many words a text has.
The text is stored in a .txt file in the same directory as my .exe file. I was wondering if there is a way to make the name of my .txt file irrelevant as long as the .txt file is in the same directory as my .exe file is? I would like to be able to change the name of the .txt file and still run my program successfully without getting a "error opening file" message.

Comment: You have two problems: The first is that there's no *standard* way to list contents of directories in C++ ([at least not yet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)). You have to use operating-system functions for that. The second problem is that your directory isn't really known either. [There might operating-system specific functions to get that as well though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable).

Comment: @DimChtz: There is no standard API for getting the executable path of the calling process (unless you count `argv[0]`, but that only applies to console apps, and it can lie).

Comment: What happens when there's two or more text files in that directory?  Maybe you should require the filename to be passed on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enumerate the files in your app's folder until you find one with a `.txt` file extension.

However, there is nothing in the standard C++ libraries to handle that.

You need to use platform-specific APIs <sup>1</sup> to determine the folder where your app is running from, and then you can use platform-specific APIs <sup>2</sup>, or a 3rd party cross-platform API <sup>3</sup>, to enumerate the files in that folder.

Once you discover the file, only then can you open it.

<sup>1</sup>: (like parsing the result of [`GetModuleFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) on Windows)
<sup>2</sup>: (like [`FindFirstFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) and [`FindNextFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx) on Windows)
<sup>3</sup>: (like [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm))

Comment: The C++17 [filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) will be almost exactly like `boost::filesystem`, so that may be worth mentioning.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: That is awhile off, though. And considering that many people still aren't even using C++11 yet, it is not likely that they are going to be jumping to C++17 right away.