# Get path of the executable using standard library

Tags: c++, filesystems, standard-library

I know it can be done using [OS specific code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937/1298196), or [Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528401/1298196), but I can't see a way to do it using the standard library [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem). Note that [current_path](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/current_path) wouldn't work as the executable might be called from a different directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path of executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable)

Comment: Still not platform independent but you might be able to use the current working directory (should be possible to get using `std::filesystem`) and resolve an absolute path using `argv[0]`.

Comment: There is no requirement that an executable even *has* a path, so it will be system specific anyway.