# use Visual Studio to embed python code in C++ without installing Python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I am working on a Python code embedding in c++ helloworld program, necessary additional include/library directories are properly set up. Now I have made it work using the answer from

[python works in c++ in debug mode, but not in exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976035/python-works-in-c-in-debug-mode-but-not-in-exe-file)

I hope my code works on my teamates' PC.  What I did was

[1] copy folder `C:/Python` to `D:/Project/Python`

[2] retrieve Python registry file, replace `C:/Python/...` by `D:/Project/Python/...`, and save a new registry file `ProjPython.reg`

[3] let my teamate save my project to `D:/Project/Python` and run `ProjPython.reg`

This is clearly very stupid, I think what it needs is just telling Visual Studio the directories of Python header, interpreter, dll and so on.

Then I searched it online, finding that I could use Python Environments in Visual Studio (i.e. Python Tool Visual Studio).

After I set up Prefix Path, Interpreter Path, Windowed Interpreter to `D:/Project/Python` `D:/Project/Python/python.exe` `D:/Project/Python/pythonw.exe`, hoping it would run successfully without editting registry, but it failed.

Anybody know how to set up Python directories in Visual Studio 2017 and later for **C++ code that containing some python scripts**. Gracias!

Comment: I sense that you are confusing Visual Studio (the development environment) and MSVC (the C++ compiler that build executables). This is an understandable confusion if you come from Python, which really is an interpreted language. The problem is, EXE files are stand-alone and generally should run on machines which do not have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: @MSalters Gracias for pointing it out. As long as necessary .dll .py and other files put in a same folder with .exe, it should work on any PC. Also I am working with a team, someone does not have Python installed, someone has different Python version, so I am hoping my team could use a unified Python (without affecting their own Python environment)

Comment: You can have multiple Python installations on Windows, including different versions and furthermore you can have separate Python virtual environments for each project.