# Get executable's path (with std::filesystem)

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

Before i get marked as duplicate, all similar questions i could find have answers prior to the introduction of std::filesystem, and either use platform-specific code or Boost::filesystem. I'm looking for a portable answer that uses std::filesystem.

---

Is it possible to get the path where a c++ executable is located (not the working directory) using std::filesystem? If it is, how?

Comment: I can't spot anything [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). So I am afraid the answer is, it's not possible.

Comment: How about the second parameter (`argv`) of the `main` function? I’m not sure how portable that is.

Comment: @Kerndog73 That won't include the full path unless the program was called using a full path.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) says that `argv[0]` is the “name used to invoke the program”. Assuming that this is an absolute path might not be portable but I really have no idea. All I can say is that on macOS it’s an absolute path.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It’s always an absolute path on macOS but probably not elsewhere

Comment: @Kerndog73 Definitely not with linux systems. It's just what was typed in at the shell, or used in a UI launcher.

Comment: How about `.`? Or does it have to be an absolute path?

Comment: You can get the absolute path using `std::filesystem` and the current directory and `argv[0]` but it is stil not "portable" as nothing says what goes in `argv[0]` in the `C++` Standard.

Comment: I think that [`std::filesystem::absolute`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute) will do what you want it to do (construct a `std::filesystem::path` object using `argv[0]`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's nothing provided in the [standard filesystem facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to get the path of your executable.

Even using using the [1st `argv` argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) isn't guaranteed to contain the full path of the executable.
The systems I know will just pass in the string that was used to launch the program.
Considering that this could be resolved using the `PATH` environment variable, there's no guarantee, you see a full path there.

There are some OS specific methods to do so though:

- [Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable)

Comment: You could use [current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) to resolve relative paths to an absolute path. But even then it is `OS` dependent. Though it should work on most systems I would think.

Comment: @Galik The current working directory has absolutely nothing to do with the executable's path.

Comment: Not on its own. You would still have to use it in conjunction with `PATH` in some instance.