# Create/Dump file using the relative path inside code with CMAKE project in c++

Tags: c++, cmake, file-io

I have a project structure like this -

```
|Project
|--data
|  |--assets
|     |--file1.txt
|     |--file2.txt  
|--Module
|  |--src
|     |--dumpFileToAssets.cpp
|--build
|  |--out.exe
```

The binary is written into `build/out.exe`. So from my understanding the relative path is wrt the binary being generated.

Code snippet from `dumpFileToAssets.cpp`

**Full path works** -

```
std::string path = "/Users/Username/Project/data/assets/file1.txt"
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (path);  
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

**Relative path from the build directory does not work -**

meaning `file1.txt` is not generated in the `.open()` call and hence not written -

```
std::string path = "./../data/assets/file1.txt"
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (path);  
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

**Question** - Is my understanding that `any relative path inside the code is wrt to the binary path where the binary is generated` correct ?

Or can I access the `Project` root path inside code to achieve this ??

**PS** :
Here are my findings -

1. When I run the binary from terminal, it works.
2. When I run an Xcode version of the project, the `out.exe` path is different, so it does not work, and I have to change the path wrt to the new `out.exe` path

Comment: No. Learn about [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Root path of the project is generally meaningless outside of your build process because executable programs, after they get built, get packaged and shipped and installed at different paths on customers' machines where there is no such thing as "the project".

Comment: True, but if I know the `build/out.exe` is generated like above, then the relative path above should work right ?

Comment: put a debug line or print the path

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: Okay so now I get it,  I run the binary from terminal, the above code works

When I run it from Xcode, the binary path is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the working directory is incorrect. There are multiple ways to run your application and each time the working directory is different

```
cd /Users/Username/Project/
./build/out.exe
```

The working directory is /Users/Username/Project/

```
cd build
./out.exe
```

The working directory is /Users/Username/Project/build

```
mkdir sub
cd sub
../out.exe
```

The working directory is /Users/Username/Project/build/sub

On Windows, the working directory may even be a different drive:

```
D:
cd \test
C:\Users\Username\Project\build\out.exe
```

The working directory is D:\test

If you want to open a file relative to the executable, then determine the [path of the executable first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982441/get-executables-path-with-stdfilesystem), which is not trivial. Note that `argv[0]` may be a symbolic link and not the executable itself (like `less` is a link to `more`).