# C++17/20 - Use <filesystem> to determine if file is executable

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17, executable

I want to know if there is a way to determine if a file in a directory is executable or not using the new C++17/20 `#include <filesystem>`. I do not want to use Boost. I know how this can be done with `stat`, `st_mode` and `S_IXUSR` but I haven't found a way to do it with pure C++17/20.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579815/11024053) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check execution [permissions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/perms), that is `owner_exec`, `group_exec` and `other_exec` attributes of the corresponding `std::experimental::filesystem::permissions` struct. Given a filename, it can be retrieved with

```cpp
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

// ...

const auto permissions = fs::status("file.txt").permissions();
```

Check these according what you know about current user (is the current user owner of file, in file's user group).

Comment: Thank you. I was searching all over, can't believe I missed this.

Comment: I don't think this is applicable to Windows? Windows doesn't really do the whole "permissions" thing. I could just check myself but I'd have to boot up Windows to do it... Ugh.