# Get exe name that is currently running (Not the path)

Tags: c++

hey so i wanted to get name of the exe that is currently running
here is what ive tried doing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
  {
  char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, filename);
  if (size)
    cout << "EXE file name is: " << filename << "\n";
  else
    cout << "Could not fine EXE file name.\n";
  return 0;
  }
```

but it gets the path of the exe too but i only need the exe name any help?

Comment: Cut at the last backslash and only keep the stuff after...? Btw, "i wanted to get path of the exe" and "it gets the path...but i only need the exe name" are mutually exclusive/confusing.

Comment: Please include output and expected output in the question. It seems like all you have to do is cut everything before and including the last `/`

Comment: Getting the name from the path should be easy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable

Comment: i dont want to get the path. only the name of the exe

Comment: **This is operating system or implementation specific**. For Linux, see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). **Some C++ implementations don't even have files** (read some C++ standard such as [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) to check). If you use [Qt](http://qt.io/) there is a way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command line argument is the name of the current program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 0)
        std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
    else {
        //some other method has to be used, use OP's suggestion
        char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
        DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
        if (!size) {
            std::cout << "Could not fine EXE file name.\n";
            return -1;
        }

        //Remove everything before the last "\"
        std::string name = filename;
        auto it = std::find(name.rbegin(), name.rend(), '\\'); //escape the escape character
        if (it != name.rend()) {
            name.erase(name.begin(), it.base());
        }

        std::cout << filename << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: This a nice easy solution for console applications. This will not work if it is a GUI application

Comment: There's no guarantee that `argv[0]` is the name of the application executable. If I use `fork()` + ones of the `exec` family of functions to launch your program I can make `argv[0]` be whatever I please. That `argv[0]` contains the executable name is only a *convention*, you cannot rely on it.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019 the first argument is "the command with which the program is invoked" if it exists.

Comment: @Mestkon See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/execl-wexecl?view=vs-2019 - you can make `argv[0]` whatever you want. Convention says it *should* be the same as the program name, but nothing enforces that. Same deal on UNIX.

Comment: none of em worked :(

Comment: Yes it does https://godbolt.org/z/Lock6d . Had to add std:: in front of the cout and add MAX_PATH parameter for it to compile.

Comment: i did already but it did not work lol