# Best way to relaunch executable (cross platform)?

Tags: c++, c++17, fork, boost-process

**Background:**

So I have client/server type of app rolled into the same executable.

What I want is if it fails to connect on the localhost, it should start itself (same executable, but with different parameters/command so to start the server). Then perhaps wait a bit and then try to connect again (only try once). This is different from, but similar, to `fork()`'ing (which I could have used, but `fork()` is not cross platform).

**Question**

I know `boost::process` can launch the process in a platform independent manner, but is there a way to obtain the path of the process so that to launch oneself (cross platform) ?

Comment: I developed a "process monitor" functionality some years ago where a second process kept the first process "alive". So that works. But I understand you want your executable to "monitor and administrate" itself? It may be hard? I suppose you have to figure out a way to initiate a new process where your executable is no longer the parent (owner)?. Good luck :)

Comment: IMHO this should be one process (w/o restarting). Just implement in your main() simple state machine:
[*] --> RunAsClient
RunAsClient  --> InitialLocalRun : failed
InitialLocalRun --> RetryRunAsClient : timeout
RetryRunAsClient --> LocalRun : failed

Comment: My main issue atm. is how to do a start the process, ie. how to get the full path to the execuatable ?

Comment: FYI: [SO: Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528493/7478597)