# How to get path for other project files inside a C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, filesystems

I'm working on a C++ project that uses some images.
To read them inside the program I need the absolute path of this image folder.
My project tree is something like:

```
images/ (png files)
include/ (header files)
bin/ (executable files)
src/ (source code)
```

Currently I'm getting the path by using the `argv[0]` from `main` function by I know that isn't a good way, especially when I call the executable from linux terminal (the `argv[0]` show the executable name only).

I prefer a solution that work both at Linux and Windows systems. This project use CMake in Linux and Visual Studio in Windows system.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem ? Helps to do most things with paths quite portably .

Comment: I assume you need `GetModuleFileNameW` for windows, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579815/4603670), you have to parse the directory path from it.