# Copying file doesn't do anything in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ and I'm trying to make a file manager used with commands. Everything was good except for the copy function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    system(*"copy \"" + argv[0] + *"\" \"C:/Users/doubl/Desktop\"");
}
```

There isn't an error when compiling and running, but it never actually transfers anything.

Is there a better way to do this? if not what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot concatenate strings like that. Also, putting in `*` in front of things randomly might get rid of errors, but it's not going to fix anything.

Comment: Why do you have pointers to strings in the system() call?

Comment: There [is a better way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) also.

Comment: To fix your actual problem, it's easiest to convert to a C++ string first. `system((std::string("copy \"") + argv[0] + "\" \"C:/Users/doubl/Desktop\"").c_str());`. As DrewDormann mentioned though, there's already this functionality built into the language.

Comment: While `"copy \""` is a C-style string, `*"copy \""` is the number `99`, the ASCII value for `c`, when added to a pointer.

Comment: It should also be noted that `argv[0]` is the name of your program, not the first argument passed to the program.

Comment: @DrewDormann When I printed `argv[0]` it showed the full path of the executable, and I was just testing so I used that.

Comment: Unrelated Note: You can't count on the full path being in `argv[0]`. It could also contain a relative path, a symlink, whatever the user typed, or whatever command was executed from a program or script. In some cases, usually bare metal embedded systems, it can be an empty string.

Comment: @user4581301 Then how would I get the executable path? Is there a more reliable way or am I doomed to count on `argv[0]` and just hope it has what I'm looking for

Comment: That, unfortunately, is target specific. Every system does it a little differently. Here is a question on the topic with answers that cover the most common systems that you'll encounter: [Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable)

Comment: I recommend using an Operating System function, don't go through `system`.  The operating was designed to efficiencly copy files and already has the code.  There's an overhead when using `system`.

Answer (score -2):

A possible way to copy files in C++ is to learn then use some existing C++ library or framework, like [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/).

Another way is to use C++ `std::string`-s, documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) to build your command line.

Newer C++ standards have `std::filesystem` documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Of course, you will spend days in reading documentation.

My recommendation is to read the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), that you might invoke as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` - all warnings and debug info). Then read the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/)).

You probably also want to read the documentation of your version control system (e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/)).

Notice that your code (even improved a bit) won't work on my computers (they all run Linux), since `copy` (as a program) does not exist on them. The near equivalent program is called `/bin/cp` part of GNU [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

I heard that `copy`  is a Windows specific program. It existed on MSDOS.

At last, some computers (e.g. [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/)) might be programmable in C++ and not even have any files.