# How to access file independent from directory I run the binary file?

Tags: c++, linux, installation, path, relative-path

In my program I want to read file placed in specific sub directory of my repository.

I use relative path to do so. But the problem is that if I execute my binary file from other directory it obviously does not work. I also don't want to use absolute path, cause someone may install my repository in other place. Is there are any way to solve this problem using C++ or may be some through some setup script?

UPD: on linux

Comment: Which operating system(s) are you targeting? Unfortunately this fundamentally requires a platform specific solution.

Comment: This may be helpful for you. Add the -fPIC compilation option when compiling dynamic libraries, then generate position-independent code.

Comment: [Position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) is about the address at which the machine code is placed within the memory, which has nothing to do with file accesses.

Comment: Is accessing files using paths relative to the path to the binary acceptable? If so, see [Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable).