# Configure define variable in cmake which can be used in build directory and after install

Tags: c++, installation, cmake

Directory structure of my program

```
my_project
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── external
│   └── folder
│       └── schema.json
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
└── unit-test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── test.cpp
```

I want to define a variable in `my_project/CMakeLists.txt` which points to `schema.json`

```
my_project/CMakeLists.txt
add_definitions(-DSCHEMA_PATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/external/folder/schema.json")
```

To use it in a code as below

```
my_project/unit-test/test.cpp
std::filesystem::path rootSchema{SCHEMA_PATH};

my_project/src/main.cpp
std::filesystem::path rootSchema{SCHEMA_PATH};
```

So after build I can directly run the executable and it works, since the json file is available at the path.

```
cmake -Bbuild -S.
cmake --build build --target all
./build/bin/runTests
```

How can use the same variable after `make install`? Since the schema json file is not present in install directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at what's happening here. You define a preprocessor variable `SCHEMA_PATH` which you set to an absolute path. This is compiled into the test and production binaries.

To make something like this work, you need to use a relative path and install `schema.json` along with your application.

Your root CMakeLists.txt should look something like this:

```
# Use a relative path from bin
add_definitions(-DSCHEMA_PATH="../external/folder/schema.json"

# Copy the file into the build directory
file(
    COPY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/folder/schema.json
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/folder
)
```

And in src/CMakelists.txt where you install your target

```
install(
    FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/folder/schema.json
    DESTINATION my/installation/dir/external/folder
)
```

As pointed out by @fabian, the relative path needs to be evaluated relative to the executable's location as pointed out in the answers to [Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable)

You should check that both the build and the installation folders have the following, identical structure:

```
install/build root
+ bin
| + my_executable
| + runTests (only in build)
+ external
  + folder
    + schema.json
```

Comment: A relative path alone won't do the trick, since the program need not be run with the installed `bin` directory as working directory. You'll need to use one of the approaches defined here to avoid this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable . Alternatively info stored e.g. in the registry during installation (assuming windows) could be used for locating the install dir...

Comment: @fabian thank you for your constructive criticism on yet another of my answers. I took the liberty of pasting your link verbatim. I also agree there are several alternatives to relative paths by using a global config (Windows registry or *NIX dotfiles) or using absolute paths in the first place. It depends. I tried to write something that's not too different from the OP's original implementation.