# Get filepath of library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libretro

I am building a library for the Libretro framework, and I want to get the path of my library so that I can open a file in the same directory as my `library.so` file.

I followed the instructions at [How to implement readlink to find the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525668/how-to-implement-readlink-to-find-the-path), but that just gives me the path of the executable that is calling my library.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, use the Glibc extension `dladdr()`.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

std::string get_library_path() {
    Dl_info dl_info;
    if(0 != dladdr((void*)get_library_path, &dl_info))
        return std::string(dl_info.dli_fname);
    else
        return std::string();
}
```

On Windows, the equivalent is `GetModuleFileName()`

Comment: This gives me an empty string.

Comment: Sorry.  `dladdr()` returns 0 on error, and nonzero on success.   Grr.  Editing the code sample to reverse the error check.