# Are there any alternatives to err() that do not terminate/exit program?

Tags: c, error-handling, exit

Is there an alternative to the err() family of functions found in <err.h> that displays the program name, a semicolon, a space, and the error message... without exiting the program?

> **Pseudocode**
>
> I want
>
> ```
> print "<program name>: <error message>"
> ```
>
> and not
>
> ```
> print "<program name>: <error message>"
> exit program
> return <status>
> ```

**EDIT:** I cannot use argv[0] (as the program name) to write out the message myself, as I am writing a library

Comment: The alternative is to write it yourself. It is not very difficult.

Comment: The problem is getting the name of the program itself. I cannot use argv[0], as I am working on a C library.

Comment: You could look at the `err` source code for insights. It is opensource. Or you can add an initialization function for your library which will be passed `argv[0]` as parameter.

Comment: On the asssumption that you know which program generates the error, you might find `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__FUNCTION__` (if supported) more useful, which can be passed by the calling function which sees an offence.

Comment: @WeatherVane I cannot assume this, as others who compile my code might name the program differently. I do not know a way to derive the invocation name before compile time, but err() somehow manages to. I have a feeling this is compiler-dependent because <err.h> is not part of the standard library...

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Is it you who wants the executable name, or the person who is using your library, and already knows the name of their own program? Or is your function internal to the library, and not user-called? One thing you can do, is to have a library initialisation call, where the user supplies the executable name (and anything else).

Comment: It is the function internal to the library that requires the executable name (what the final program is compiled as).

Comment: *but err() somehow manages to*  If `err()` can do it, [you can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031672/without-access-to-argv0-how-do-i-get-the-program-name).

Answer (score 0):

See `man error`.

`error` is the same as `err` but will return if `status == 0`, exit otherwise.

> CONFORMING TO
>
> - These functions and variables are GNU extensions, and should not be used in programs intended to be portable.

Comment: It states ": Operation not permitted" after invocation of error() before exiting. While I have not gotten this approach to work, I have found out about `program_invocation_name` through the same man page you me, though. By using `extern` I was able to successfully print the error message with the program name!

Comment: Wow, i've tested it right now and this it what i got: _Interrupted system call_. I have to admit, i never used `error` before, i need to do some research on that.

Answer (score 0):

`program_invocation_name` works just as well for getting the name of the program, as Erdal Küçük mentioned. From this, we can print the full error message, program name included.

The variable is part of glibc and can be retrieved using:

`extern char *program_invocation_name;`

Because it is not a part of the C standard library, programs using this variable should not be expected to be portable.

Comment: `program_invocation_name` is a glibc feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `warn`/`warnx` functions from `err.h` will do the same thing as `err`, but will return.

For example:

```c
warnx("message here");
puts("I'm still running!");
```

Output:

```
a.out: message here
I'm still running!
```