# How do the err/warn functions get the program name?

Tags: c, bsd

From the `err`/`warn` manpage:

```
The  err()  and  warn()  family of functions display a formatted error
message on the standard error output.  In all cases, the last component
of the program name, a colon character, and a space are output.  If the
fmt argument is not NULL, the printf(3)-like formatted error message is
output.
```

If I make this call: `warn("message");` it will output something like this:

```
a.out: message: (output of strerror here)
```

How do the `warn`/`err` functions find the name of the program (in this case, `a.out`) without seemingly having any access to `argv` at all? Does it have anything to do with the fact that they are BSD extensions?

Comment: You have tagged this with C, but `err` and `warn` are not standard C functions. You should identify the specific C implementation you are using and, if possible, provide a link to the documentation for its `err` and `warn` functions (possibly [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/warn)). When asking questions, always identify the specific things you are asking about. Even if you do not know which standard they are from, you can say they are on your system, and your system is Linux version xxx or Windows, and so on.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The `err`/`warn` functions don't conform to any standard, they are BSD extensions, but work on any system with `libbsd` or a working `err.h` installed. Since this applies to nearly all Linux systems, I think it's acceptable to tag the question as C. (Maybe "BSD extensions" would be a better tag?)

Comment: I did not say you should not tag the question as C; I meant that, when you are asking about things that are not specified by the C standard, it is **insufficient** to tag the question with C. You must also specify where the functions are coming from, which can be done either via tags or via text in the post. Posting a question tagged C asking about `err` without saying where `err` comes from is like posting a question tagged Book asking about the character Rebecca without saying which book it is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil At the end of my question, I did state that the functions are BSD extensions. Maybe I should've put that at the top or something. I wasn't sure if there was a BSD extensions tag, which is why I didn't use one.

Comment: The functions have somehow access to the command line arguments. If you want to find out, get the relevant source code which is certainly available somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure standard C, there's no way to get the program name passed as `argv[0]` without getting it, directly or indirectly, from `main`. You can pass it as an argument to functions, or save it in a global variable.

But system functions also have the option of using system-specific methods. On open-source operating system, you can download the source code and see how it's done. For Unix-like systems, that's libc.

For example, on [FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/libc):

- The [`warn` and `err` functions](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/libc/gen/err.c) call the internal system function `_getprogname()`.
- [`_getprogname()`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/libc/gen/getprogname.c) reads the global variable `__progname`.
- `__progname` is set in [`handle_argv`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/csu/common/ignore_init.c) which is called from `_start()`. This code is not in libc, but in [CSU](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/tree/main/lib/csu), which is a separate library containing program startup code.
- `_start()` is the program's entry point. It's defined in the architecture-specific [`crt1*.c`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/csu/amd64/crt1_c.c). It's also the function that calls `main`, and it passes the same `argv` to both `handle_argv()` and `main()`.
- `_start` is the first C function called in the program. It's called from [assembly code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/csu/i386/crt1_s.S) that reads the `argv` pointer from the stack.
- The program arguments are copied into the program's address space by the kernel as part of the [implementation of the `execve` system call](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_exec.c?v=FREEBSD-12-0#L213).

Note that there are several concepts of “program name” and they aren't always equivalent. See [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe) for a discussion of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The `err`/`warn` functions prepend the basename of the program name. According to the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031672/without-access-to-argv0-how-do-i-get-the-program-name) SO post, there are a few ways to get the program name without access to `argv`.

One way is to call `readlink` on `/proc/self/exe`, then call `basename` on that. A simple program that demonstrates this:

```c
#include <libgen.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *
progname(void)
{
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    if (readlink("/proc/self/exe", path, PATH_MAX) == -1)
        return NULL;

    /* not sure if a basename-returned string should be
     * modified, maybe don't use this in production */
    return basename(path);
}

int
main(void)
{
    printf("%s: this is my fancy warn message!\n", progname());
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use the nonstandard variables `__progname`, which may not work depending on your compiler, and `program_invocation_short_name`, which is a GNU extension defined in `errno.h`.

Comment: yep, `__progname` works too, and is set by the glibc loader upon initializing your program, i.e. before `main` is even called. Good detective work on the /proc/self/exe, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How do the warn/err functions find the name of the program (in this case, a.out) without seemingly having any access to argv at all? Does it have anything to do with the fact that they are BSD extensions?

Such things can easily be figured out using the `strace` utility, which records all system calls.

I wrote the highly complex program test.c:

```c
#include <err.h>
int main() { warn("foo"); }
```

and `gcc -o test -static test.c; strace ./test` yields (the `-static` to avoid the noise from trying to load a lot of libraries):

```
execve("./test", ["./test"], 0x7fffcbb7fd60 /* 101 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd388d6540) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x201e000
brk(0x201edc0)                          = 0x201edc0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x201e3c0)      = 0
set_tid_address(0x201e690)              = 55889
set_robust_list(0x201e6a0, 24)          = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="workhorse", ...}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/tmp/test", 4096) = 9
getrandom("\x43\xff\x90\x4b\xa8\x82\x38\xdd", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(0x203fdc0)                          = 0x203fdc0
brk(0x2040000)                          = 0x2040000
mprotect(0x4b6000, 16384, PROT_READ)    = 0
write(2, "test: ", 6)                   = 6
write(2, "foo", 3)                      = 3
write(2, ": Success\n", 10)             = 10
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

And there you have it: you can just `readlink` /proc/self/exe to know what you're called.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The question was: "How do the warn/err functions find the name of the program (in this case, a.out) without seemingly having any access to argv at all? ", and you might want to read my answer's last sentence.

Comment: I'm not familiar wit linux, and TBH I didn't get the meaning of the sentence either...

Comment: well, you didn't understand it but were sure it doesn't answer the question? Thank you for just asking what it means!

Comment: The name of the program is contained in what `readlink` returns on /proc/self/exe; hope that's better? If not, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: @Jabberwocky I would say it does answer the question

Comment: @Jabberwocky note that this answer addresses someone who seems to already have good basic grasp of Linux, so you not understanding it is kind of unfortunate, but maybe not too bad.

Comment: using `gcc -static` so you can `strace` without dynamic linking-related nonsense is a VERY good tip, thank you for the answer

Comment: @spitemim you're more than welcome! Took me years to notice :)