# how to get running application path on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

To get current directory I found :

```
  if (!getcwd(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath) / sizeof(char))) {
    lililog.log(LILILog::error,"Error getting current directory path");
  }
```

But I need to get directory of running application. How to make it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Get Application Directory *NIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051859/c-get-application-directory-nix)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement readlink to find the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525668/how-to-implement-readlink-to-find-the-path)

Comment: but I want directory without executing app name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nonportable solution: read the symlink `/proc/self/exe`.

Comment: but I need this path without application name

Comment: @Alessa then take the dirname() of the readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, bufsize);