# Loading images relative to the binary

Tags: c++, sdl

I am attempting to load some images into a very basic C++/SDL based program. The images are loaded using `SDL_LoadBMP`. I have the image loading and everything seems to work perfectly. My problem is that the image is loaded relative to where I call the program from.

So I have a directory structure that goes something like this.

```
project/
    src/
        source.cpp
    assets/
        image.bmp
    bin/
        program
```

When I execute the program from the project directory (`./bin/program`) it has to use a path of `assets/image.bmp` to load the image. Is there any way I can use a relative path of `../assets/image.bmp` so the program can be executed from anywhere?

I think I need something that provides the absolute path to the program that I can then append my paths to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, `/proc/self/exe` is a symbolic link to the executable of the current process. So you can use `readlink` to find its path. From there you can use usual path manipulation to find your resources. Perhaps you should cater for the case where the program executable is again a symlink to the location where your binary lies, i.e. do some more realink as long as the current path is a symlink.

There once was a question about [finding current executable's path without `/proc/self/exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe) which also asked about a portable interface, but no single solution that caters for all needs was given in the accepted answer.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be so difficult. So a simple relative path such as `../path` or `./path` won't do? I guess I will have to build or find a nice function that will work in most places. I aim for Linux but I would like to have the option to cross-compile later.

Comment: And what about `basename`? Any reason why that should not be used? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1019557/455137

Comment: A relative path is always relative to the current working directory, which might be completely unrelated to the directory where your binary resides. If you are mainly targeting Linux, also read [section 1.14 of the Unix Programming Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC23). It advises against use of binary-relative paths.

Comment: `basename(path)` basically returns the part of `path` following the last occurrence of `'/'`. So you'd need a path to start with, and even then you are probably more interested in `dirname` than `basename`. Both fall into the category of “usual path manipulation” I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows:

1. `GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...` gets you full path to your binary
2. `PathRemoveFileSpec(...` leaves you directory only
3. `PathCombine(..., _T("..\\..\\image.bmp"))` with result of item 2 above gets you fully qualified path to image