# Find the path to the executable

Tags: path, go

I compile a program with Go for various platforms and run it by calling a relative path or just by its name (if it is in the PATH variable).

Is it possible to find out where the executable is?

Say, my program is called "`foo`(`.exe`)". I can run `./foo`, `foo` (if it's in the PATH), `../../subdir/subdir/foo`.

I have tried to use `os.Args[0]` and I guess I should check if the program name contains something different besides "foo". If yes, use `filepath.Abs`, if no, use (I can't find the function name, there is a function that looks through the PATH to check where the program is).

Comment: LookPath - http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath - may be the function you are looking for

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use package [osext](https://github.com/kardianos/osext).

It's providing function `Executable()` that returns an absolute path to the current program executable.
It's portable between systems.

[Online documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/kardianos/osext)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/kardianos/osext"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    filename, _ := osext.Executable()
    fmt.Println(filename)
}
```

Comment: It would be great if this also worked with `go run executable.go`.

Comment: You can always make request on package issue tracker: https://bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext/issues
But I don't know if it will be possible.

Comment: @DobrosławŻybort I use osext in a current project an it works fine.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18537792/2979435) is a native solution that works for me

Answer (score 49):

You can use [`os.Executable`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable) for getting executable path on Go 1.8 or above version.

```
import (
    "os"
    "path"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
    dir := path.Dir(ex)
    log.Print(dir)
}
```

Comment: Good to know, I'll try it and remove the stuff I had before.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18537792/2979435) is another native solution that works for me

Answer (score 4):

This is not go-specific (unless the go "standard library" contains some function to do it), and there is no portable solution. For solutions on some common platforms, see e.g. [How do I find the location of the executable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c)  or [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937) .