# How to test Go programs with relative directories?

Tags: testing, go

From the testing docs:

*"The package is built in a temporary directory so it does not interfere with the non-test installation."*

So any code working with directories relative to the executable will not be present relative to Temp\go-build......

In other words, given the following:

.\helloplanet.go

.\planets\planetary.res

.\helloplanet_test.go

```
go test
```

Produces an exe in Temp\go-build... but it doesn't also re-create a planets\ subdir there, so any code in helloplanet.exe looking for planets\planetary.res of course won't find it.

How should one deal with this?

Comment: You should be careful making any assumptions about the whereabouts of your executable. Your best guess is to access test files relative to $GOPATH in my opinion.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Your tests should be part of your package, and it shouldn't matter where it's built; the relative location is the same.

Comment: @FUZxxl It's not so much that I'm making assumptions about the whereabouts of the executable as I am about the subdir relative to the executable.

Comment: @JimB I have tried.  Package is main.  It wouldn't matter where the executable is placed by go test if subdirs were also copied to that location, but just running go test doesn't do that.  It looks as though the -i flag might be useful if the subdir contained packaged .go code, but what if it's eg json files?

Comment: Even though the package is built in a temporary dir, the CWD is still the package directory when the test is executed. Do an `os.Getwd()`.

Comment: @JimB Ah.  I was using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537257/golang-how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file ? Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though the test files are built in a temporary location, your working directory will be where you expect it. If you execute an `os.Getwd()` from within a test function, you'll see that your working directory is the package directory. This should work the same when running `go test` from within your package, or calling it with the full import path, as long as your package's location is in GOPATH.

In my packages, I often have a testadata directory, which is accessed via it's relative path, and have had no issues.

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  I was using `filepath.Dir(os.Args[0])`.

Comment: Turns out though, that using os.Getwd() my program now needs to be run from the directory it's in ie if I'm in `~/` and run `./myprogdir/helloplanet` it doesn't see `myprogdir/planets/planetary.res`.  That is, os.Getwd() gets the user's wd, not the program's wd.

Comment: @10cls: yes, that's what "working directory" means. I didn't mean to actually use Getwd() to find your data, just to show where the tests were running. How your program configures itself at runtime is usually different than for tests.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Too many hoops.  I'll see if I can avoid testing from temp/go-build/ or something.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that *actually* works. I found this buried in the [jetbrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009685279/comments/360002183640). Here's the answer that user Daniil Maslov came up with :

---

The trick is actually very simple and is to get the current executing and add `..` to the project root.

Create a new directory and file like `testing_init.go` with the following content:

```golang
package testing_init

import (
  "os"
  "path"
  "runtime"
)

func init() {
  _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
  dir := path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "..")
  err := os.Chdir(dir)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

After that, just import the package into any of the test files:

```golang
package main_test

import (
  _ "project/testing_init"
)
```

Now you can specify paths from the project root