# Executing a Golang binary from PHP's shell_exec() function

Tags: php, go

I have compiled a golang binary that takes 1 argument,  generates a PDF file,  and then uploads it to AWS S3. The binary works perfectly in the shell, however when trying to execute it using PHP's `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, `passthru()` and `service()` functions, it will not execute (no error messages or log entries). I have even tried calling a shell script (.sh) from PHP's shell_exec which executes the binary (also works fine in the shell), but to no avail.

Permissions are fine and PHP's `shell_exec()` works for all other instances.

Comment: If you see no error messages, how do you know it didn't execute? No news is good news, no?

Comment: :) The golang binary displays all AWS upload output (ETAG) so even when I `echo shell_exec(/path/to/binary)` it should output a response

Comment: Have you tried to add `2>&1` at the end of your command? For instance, if your command is: `shell_exec('your_script.sh');` it would become `shell_exec('your_script.sh 2>&1');`

Comment: @mdexp Just tried different variations to your suggestion but no luck yet

Comment: pls provide execution string which is used in php-script

Comment: Maybe require sudo pass to exec  to shell_exec ,are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec function Maybe require password of sudo ,

Linux pipe for sudo password

```
shell_exec('echo "YOURPASS" | sudo -u root -S your_script.sh');
```

Comment: I discovered my own issue which I posted. Thanks much for your input!

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should running something using sudo be required?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I  found my own answer:

It turns out that the GoLang binary was having issues finding assets associated with the directory path of the binary file itself. For anyone having these same issues it turns out that [@Intermernet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537257/how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file) will help you a great deal. (Please note that @Intermernet's answer is not the accepted answer)

In my case, the compiled binary was not able to locate assets (pdf, images etc) from the executable working directory.

For anyone compiling a portable golang binary that needs to keep track of assets, the following code will be your friend:

```
ex, err := os.Executable()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
exPath := filepath.Dir(ex)
```

Note that `exPath` will not be the same between the `go run` and `go build`. So you need to test with the build version.

Why I did not get any error messages I'll reserve for another question on my part.