# Using relative file paths in Go as function parameters

Tags: go, path, relative-path

Lets say I have a folder structure like so:

```
src/
- main.go
data/
- example.csv
csv/
- parse.go
utils/
- mapFields.go
```

The mapFields function takes in input and output csv files as paramters:

```
MapFields(csvInPath string, csvOutPath string) {...}
```

I want to be able to call this mapFields function from any .go file using relative file paths. For example, from main.go:

```
MapFields("../data/example.csv", "../data/output.csv")
```

I cannot figure out how to ensure MapFields opens a csv using a path created from the file path of the calling function joined with the relative path of the csv.

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537257/how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file) stack overflow post to implement a solution to get the equivalent of __dirname in Node.js, but there is no success.

I'd appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Do not use hard coded `/` slashes. Use `os.PathSeparator` instead.

Comment: `filepath.Join()` is a nice option as well.

Comment: regardless of finding the correct relative path in development, how do you intend to locate the files when deploying the binary which is not in this source directory? The solution to that question likely eliminates your relative paths problem.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your explanation. I wrote the answer in detail based on your explanation. If you can spare a time, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

File path **is resolved in context of your current working directory**.

During development it is usually the root directory of your project.
You can check what is your current directory using `os.Getwd()`.

```golang
func main() {
    if workingDirectory, err := os.Getwd(); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("cennot get working direcory - %s", err))
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Working direcory is %s", workingDirectory)
    }
}
```

For more flexibility consider using environment variable to indicate the root directory for your csv files.
if environment variable is not set use `filepath.Join(".", "data")`.

Comment: Your working directory is usually only within your project during development. The compiled binary and deployment have no relationship to the source at all.

Answer (score 0):

@JimB and @m-szalik write good answers and advices. That looks good enough to solve your problem.
But I try to summarize the answers in my style.

## Summary

You need to put the input files in the directories aligned with the working directory of the compiled and executed binary file, Rather than the directory of your development environment.

You can run your binary `main` from your code, using `../data/example.csv` in the `src` folder, in the below file hierarchy. The important thing is where your binary will be executed.

```
// run main at ./src
➜  src ./main                

// file hierarchy
.
├── data
│   ├── example.csv
│   └── output.csv
└── src
    ├── main
    └── main.go
```

## Definitions we have to know

In short, `relative path` is depending on `the working directory` where `your compiled and executed binary file` runs.

Therefore, JimB said `the compiled binary` matters.

#### Absolute path

> An **absolute or full path** points to the same location in a file system, regardless of the current working directory. To do that, it must include the root directory.

#### Relative path

> By contrast, a **relative path** starts from some given working directory,
> ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

#### Working directory

> In computing, the **working directory of a process** is a directory of a hierarchical file system, if any, dynamically associated with the process. It is sometimes called the current working directory (CWD),

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

## Simplified example

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Human struct {
    Life string `json:"life"`
}

func main() {
    var human Human
    data, errRead := os.ReadFile("txt/input")
    errUnMarshall := json.Unmarshal(data, &human)

    fmt.Println(errRead)
    fmt.Println(errUnMarshall)
    fmt.Println(human)
}
```

This code reads `input` text from its relative path `txt/`
And its directories and files are like this.

```
.
└── src
    ├── main
    ├── main.go
    └── txt
        └── input
```

##### Case 1

I run `main` on `src/`. Then it works.
The reason is `main`'s working directory `src/` and it corresponds with `os.ReadFile("txt/input")`

it prints like this. `input` text contains `{"life":"Life is hard"}` string.

```
➜  src ./main                
<nil>
<nil>
{Life is hard}
```

##### Case 2

I run `main` on `.`. Then it fails.
The reason is `main`'s working directory `.` and it doesn't correspond with `os.ReadFile("txt/input")`

```
➜ . ./src/main 
open txt/input: no such file or directory
unexpected end of JSON input
{}
```

##### Etc

You can find the working directory is the directory where your binary runs in terminal. The important thing is what directory the program runs at.

If you're using IDE such as IntelliJ, then you can set the working directory at Run/Debug configuration.
[image]