# build small image from scratch (open: no such file or directory)

Tags: docker, go

I tried to use scratch to build a small image. I turned off the CGO but still fail to read the file when the program runs. I have got the error: "open ./app/a.txt: no such file or directory". Is there other reasons that the program cannot read the file?

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/scratch
ADD . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -tags netgo -ldflags '-w -extldflags "-static"' -o /go/bin/scratch

FROM scratch
# Copy static executable.
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/scratch /go/bin/scratch
# Run the binary.
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/scratch"]
```

```
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
    check(err)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(len(body))
    LocalFile := "./app/a.txt"
    fmt.Println(LocalFile)

    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(LocalFile)
    check(err)
    fmt.Print(string(dat))

    f, err := os.Open(LocalFile)
    check(err)

    b1 := make([]byte, 5)
    n1, err := f.Read(b1)
    check(err)
    fmt.Printf("%d bytes: %s\n", n1, string(b1[:n1]))
}
func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error says: the file or directory does not exist. Most likely, your code is not running from the directory you think it is.

Comment: Have you copied "./app/a.txt" into your docker image? Just to confirm, can you do docker exec /bin/bash and see if the file is there in the directory?

Comment: There are a bunch of problems. The first one is "why do you expect "./app/a.txt" to exist in a scratch image that has exactly two files in it?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by moving the text file outside of my source code, so the path can be found when I use env variable

Answer (score 2):

`alpine` does not provide `glibc`. `alpine` is that small because it uses a stripped down version of libstdc called [musl.libc.org](https://musl.libc.org/).

So we'll check statically linked dependencies using `ldd` command.

```
$ docker run -it <image name> /bin/sh
$ cd /go/bin
$ ldd scratch   # or the excutable you are calling-> ldd <executable>
```

Check the linked static files, do they exist on that version of alpine? If the do not from, the binaries perspective, it did not find the file-- and will report `File not found`.

The following step depends on what binaries were missing, you can look it up on the internet on how to install them.

Add `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat` to your Dockerfile to add `libstdc` in some `Golang` alpine image based Dockerfiles.

In you case the solution is to either

- disable CGO : use `CGO_ENABLED=0` while building
- or add
   `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat`
  to your `Dockerfile`
- or do not use `golang:alpine`

Comment: This is definitely a problem- but not the problem that the error message is pointing them to.

Comment: @frozenOne thank you for your information. my code in dockerfile is fine, but I made a mistake to include the text file inside of my source code, which I cannot read the path once the program got complied.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake to compile the go program with the txt file the program would like to read. That's why the file path was not correct once the program compiled to binary exec.
Just in case someone made the same mistake like me, here's is one of my solution.
I solved the problem by moving the text file outside of my project and use env variable to point to the path i want.

I think package "osext" is another way to do it.
[Find the path to the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090170/find-the-path-to-the-executable)