# how to find the location of the executable in C in OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos

Exactly like [How do I find the location of the executable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c) but for Mac OS X. I am aware that argv[0] probably works, but I want a way to programmatically access this information (i.e. a function call) as the code I am writing is part of a library which does not have access to argv[0].

Comment: On linux it's available by looking at `/proc/self/exe`. Maybe OS X has something similar?

Comment: @FatalError it does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X implements the functions:

```
int _NSGetExecutablePath(char * buf, uint32_t * length);
int * _NSGetArgc(void);
char *** _NSGetArgv(void);
```

The first of these is probably what you want here. The other two are interesting as well, though!