# POSIX: How do you determine your own process's file image so you can exec yourself?

Tags: c, linux, exec, posix, fork

How does one determine the file that represents the current process' executable?

The problem is that `argv[0]` is not reliable, as if it was called via `execXp`, the path entry that satisfied a non-qualified command may or may not be prepended. Furthermore, ANY caller to `exec*` can replace `argv[0]` with ANYTHING.

Hence, if you run `ps`, you are not guaranteed that `argv[0]` will be `"/usr/bin/ps"`. In fact, you're probably guaranteed the OPPOSITE.

I need one of the following:

1. the full path name (without doing a path search myself, lest the envp I am using is not the one the shell used)
2. a live, pre-opened file descriptor to the file that corresponds to the current process' image
3. some magic descriptor that corresponds to the code segment currently in memory (not quite sure about the BSS segment, though)

In this way, at startup I can quickly open an FD to my own executable (for case 1., in case the file gets removed and becomes unopenable), and then at a much later date call:

```
int fexecve(int fd, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

to `fork`/`exec` myself (typically needed on OS-X to work around the unreliability of the global and system descriptor state after `fork()`  ). In other words (this example is silly, of course):

```
void magicallyReplicate(argc, argv)
{
  if (!fork()) {
    magicallyExecMyself(argc, argv);
  }
}
```

or even just:

```
void startOver(argc, argv)
{
  magicallyExecMyself(argc, argv);
}
```

Of course, in my example, I will be using different `argv`'s so that I can run in a different mode.

(early "no" retort: you can't use `clone()`, as it is of `fork()`'s lineage)

Comment: `How does one determine the file that represents the current process' executable?`. Is it OK for you how pmap determines the file that represents a process? As an example it starts its output like this for example for bash process:  `0000000000400000    848K r-x--  /bin/bash`.

Comment: Any way that gets me the path or an open FD is fine. I do not even believe the current seek point matters to fexecve.

Comment: Then why don't you just read /proc/PID/maps? It contains in the first line the file name for a running process.

Comment: /proc/pid isn't POSIX compliant...otherwise, I would. Great idea though, would be great on LINUX!

Comment: Your question has tag `linux` by the way

Comment: Great question! Several duplicates on SO already...

Comment: Also less-good answer but with a bit more discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c

Comment: @Nicholas...the problem is that while the question may be asked repeatedly, it's subtle enough that the format of the question(s) did not match previous incarnations, and thus were not matched. I spent a LONG time on The Google before giving up. In general, the subtle questions are going to be like this; much of the low-hanging fruit has been picked. And frankly, bully for the multiple asks: each one tends to be worded slightly differently, resulting in a better chance that a future querier will find without needing to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, the easiest platform to do this on is MacOS (because libc is totally broken and simple things like getaddrinfo segfault if called between `fork` and `exec`) - on Darwin, the kernel hands you on a plate the full binary name when it starts up the process. Retrieve it with the fourth argument to main (http://web.archive.org/web/20170816030258/http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/02/char-apple-argument-vector.html) or with _NSGetExecutablePath which is exactly the same - it's just a function that knows about the identical special position where the kernel puts the filename.

For all platforms, it's a case-by-case matter. Full details in this thread: [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937)

Comment: Holy cow, man, y'er a hero! Thanks! BTW, Darwin and MacOS are my first platforms, so doubleplusgood.