# how c program get non complete address of input file

Tags: c

I have a program in c. Input of this program is the address of a file. This program gets the complete address of input file like d:\bin\files\examples\data\file.txt. How can I correct the program that gets input in form of data\file.txt ? and the d:\bin\files\examples\ add itself.

Comment: If you dont want to enter your full path you can enter a path relative to your executable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c

Comment: What do you mean by "add itself"?

Comment: How can I enter a path relative to executable?

Comment: `..` means up a directory...

Comment: show us examples of running your command and explain better what's wrong and how do you want this program to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it. while the c program is below the directory *d:/bin/files/examples* and compile ,then execute it with the direct argument *data/file.txt*.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [getcwd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) function. You will get current working directory path. Apply your logic what part to add. Use [sprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) to complete the path.