# Can an executable dynamically resolve its location on the filesystem or its actual "resting place" vs just the working directory of the user?

Tags: linux, go, path, pid, working-directory

If I have an executable in `/usr/bin` and call it while I'm located at `~/dev/wikis/` (that is `user@HAL:~/dev/wikis$ the_executable`), the `ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt")` function in the executable will look in `/home/user/dev/wikis/file.txt`, but is it possible to make it look in `/usr/bin/file.txt` instead without the user or developer knowing beforehand that the executable will be located in `/usr/bin` (it could just as well be located in `/home/user/dev/my_program/the_executable`)?

And then to add a layer of complexity, another situation, say I call the executable from a *symbolic link* in `/usr/bin` with the "source" of the executable actually being in `/home/user/dev/my_program/the_executable`, and I want the program to know about `/home/user/dev/my_program/` in this case, dynamically, rather then `/usr/bin`.

**In short:** How can an executable dynamically resolve its location on the filesystem or its actual "resting place" vs the working directory of the user (which can easily be gotten through `os.Getwd()` and which other commands like `ioutil.ReadFile` use, or use something comparible, for resolving paths).

My best bet is that I have to get the PID of the running program (`os.Getpid`) and then somehow use that integer to access information about the instance of the program running under that PID, and hopefully that information contains a string of its directory which I can then use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux (and perhaps in other Unixy systems) you'll find a symbolic link to the actual executable running as `pid` under `/proc/pid/exe`, checking that one will give what you want if it is a binary. If it is a script of some sort, that will probably just give the interpreter.

But note that it is perfectly possible to start a process and delete the executable while it is running, leaving either a dangling link or just nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the language but as far as I know most programming languages have a way to get either the 'basename' of the program, e.g. helloworld, or the full path, e.g. /usr/bin/helloworld. Often this is provided as the first argument to the program, inserted by the OS/runtime library/interpreter, etc. For example, in C, argv[0] (as we start counting from 0 in C) gives the name of the current program, but the calling process initialises this special argument so the exact format can vary, and in bash, $0 will expand into the path of the script as given when executed (I think). From here: https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments, "os.Args provides access to raw command-line arguments. Note that the first value in this slice is the path to the program, and os.Args[1:] holds the arguments to the program." So it appears you don't need to worry about /proc but if you're interested, [How do I find the location of the executable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The exported variable `os.Args` (which is a slice: `[]string`) holds the program arguments, its first element being the executable name with full path.

If the executable is not a symlink, you can use the [`path`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/) or [`filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) packages to get the folder of the executable like this:

```
folder := filepath.Dir(os.Args[0])
```

And you can use [`os.Readlink()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Readlink) to resolve a symbolic link.

And to test if your executable is a symlink, you can use [`os.Lstat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat) which makes no attempt to follow a link (as opposed to [`os.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat)).

So your final version should look like this:

```
s := os.Args[0]
fi, err := os.Lstat(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // Failed to get stats
}

// Check if it's a symlink and if so, try to resolve it
if fi.Mode()&os.ModeSymlink != 0 {
    if s, err = os.Readlink(s); err != nil {
        panic(err) // Failed to resolve symlink
    }
}
s = filepath.Dir(s) // We only want the folder part
```

Comment: This still fails if the command was called via a relative path and the process changed directories, or if the executable was found from PATH. In the former case, there's no way to know for sure (that's why we parse `/proc`), and the latter case you can try to find the correct executable in PATH (`exec.LookPath` can do this).