# Ada Finding executable location

Tags: executable, ada

Similar to [How do I find the location of the executable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c) , but in Ada.

Is there a nice package that I can use to determine the executable location in a cross-platform manner? (Windows & Linux)

Nothing has been turned up on Google, or a look through GNAT/Ada packages

Failing an existing package, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

`Ada.Command_Line.Command_Name` gives you the name of the executable.  On Linux, this gives you the name as you called the program.  Since you often just use `ls` and let the shell search the path for the actual executable, you will have to reimplement that functionality yourself on top of `Ada.Command_Line` and `Ada.Directories`.

Comment: Needed a `Ada.Directories.Containing_Directory` wrapping around it, but otherwise exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: ...Except it appears to be blank on Linux. Any idea about that?

Comment: At a guess this is because this code is running inside a (dynamic) library, rather than the executable itself. Who knows how it managed to work on Windows

Answer (score 1):

As @egilhh [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342257/ada-finding-executable-location/46343133?noredirect=1#comment79647562_46343133), the language defined approach is to use the `Current_Directory` function provided by [`Ada.Directories`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-16.html).

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Directories;

procedure PWD is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ada.Directories.Current_Directory);
end PWD;
```

As cross-platform behavior is critical to your use case, you'll need to test on representative targets. You may also want to study the corresponding `Ada.Directories` implementations. Use `gnatkr` to determine the relevant file names. Given an environment variable named `ADA_INC` that points to your `adainclude` directory,

```
export ADA_INC=${ADA_HOME}/lib/gcc/…/adainclude
```

the following commands should let you view the relevant sources:

```
view $ADA_INC/$(gnatkr Ada.Directories.ads)
view $ADA_INC/$(gnatkr Ada.Directories.adb)
```

Note that `Current_Directory` imports a `C` function that is compiled for each supported platform and installed with the distribution. In contrast, `Containing_Directory` handles Windows as a special case explicitly.

Finally, you can implement any of the [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/933850/230513) approaches by importing a suitable function or by invoking `Spawn` and `Expect`, as shown in [*Gem #54: Scripting Capabilities in GNAT (Part 2)*](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-54/)

Comment: that doesn't work if i'm running from a different directory though, e.g. `../../bin/executable`

Comment: (Assume I'm deep inside a library and probably can't access argv[0] (or whatever Ada's equivalent is)

Comment: (@trashgod, no need to use GNAT-specifics here, `Ada.Directories.Current_Directory` is more portable)

Comment: LordAro: @egilhh suggests the better approach. Sorry for the [wrong turn](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46343133/1).

Comment: well, @Jacob Sparre Andersen has an even better answer... `Ada.Command_Line.Command_Name` corresponds to argv[0]...

Comment: @egilhh: I thought that LordAro wanted the _location_ rather than the name; sorry off I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: You are correct, but that was a simple Containing_Directory away so I've accepted the other solution. However, I did want to use the current directory as well, so this is also useful!