# Get path of executable (compiled c program) and path from where it is called, in linux

Tags: c, linux

I have an executable file `mzApp` (compiled c program by gcc compiler) in a directory `/root/home/mzApplication`.

I run this file from another directory i.e. `/root/home/check` and from this location, I issued the following command to run the application `./root/home/mzApplication/mzApp`.

Now I want to get both of the following paths in my c application

1. Where exe file is located i.e. `/root/home/mzApplication`
2. From where this application is called i.e. `/root/home/check`

Please suggest an efficient way to do this!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, @izlin. This link has a way to get exe path. But also want to get a path from where the application is invoked.

Comment: I can't find a dupe, but you'd use `getcwd`. Also, I recommend not asking multiple different questions per post.