# How to open a file relative to the executables location in C?

Tags: c, file, permissions

Let's say the compiled C binary is located at `~/bin/my_cool_c_program.out` and I have the following code:

```
FILE *file = fopen("helloworld.txt");
perror("Open helloworld.txt");
```

Now I face the problem, that the code creates the `helloworld.txt` file in the directory where I'm executing the binary from and not relative from where the binary is located. So calling it from `~` results in the creation of `~/helloworld.txt`, but I want it to save it to `~/bin/helloworld.txt`. I tried replacing it with `"./helloworld"`, but that didn't work, too. When I call from the `~/bin/` directory itself everything works as expected.

And why is it, that the first one results in `perror` printing `Permission denied` after the file gets created, while the second one prints `Successful`?

---

NOTE: I do check for `file == NULL` and so on. I just removed it for simplicity.

Comment: You may find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe)

Comment: I didn't expect, that there was no standard for this 

Comment: The second argument which indicates the opening mode is missing in the fopen call.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to do this.
If the string pointed to by `argv[0]` (`argv` is the second parameter of `main` function, though any other name may be used), representing the program name, contains path of the program (there is no such a guarantee), then the code below can be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* filename separator (depends on the operating system) */
#define SEP '/'

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *fp;
        const char *filename = "helloworld.txt";
        const char *lastslash;
        if (argc > 0 && (lastslash = strrchr(argv[0], SEP)) != NULL) {
                const int len = lastslash - argv[0] + 1;
                char *const pathname = malloc(len + strlen(filename) + 1);
                if (pathname == NULL) {
                        perror("malloc");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                sprintf(pathname, "%.*s%s", len, argv[0], filename);
                fp = fopen(pathname, "w");
                free(pathname);
                if (fp == NULL) {
                        perror("fopen");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
        } else {
                fputs("No path information in argv[0]\n", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into your code but I'll use [this library](https://github.com/gpakosz/whereami)

Comment: If argv[0] starts with "/" (absolute path) this is the path.

    Otherwise if argv[0] contains "/" (relative path) append it to cwd (assuming it hasn't been changed yet).

    Otherwise search directories in $PATH for executable argv[0].

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/933996) answer.

Looking for the program in `$PATH` will make it work most of the time