# Executing a jar file, with code

Tags: java, launching

I'm trying to create a java launcher to launch other .jar programs. When you click on a button in the launcher, I want it to run a different .jar file. not the .java file. I am not sure if this is even possible. 
If it's possible, how can this be done?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936266/execute-jar-file-from-a-java-program.

Comment: That only sort of answers my question. I want this to be able to run on any computer, if I set the java path to my path on my personal computer then it will not be able to run on anyone's computer.

Comment: @EvanNudd maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392416/determining-location-of-jvm-executable-during-runtime can help a bit. No actual solution though. If you don't need a specific JVM, you may additionally try invoking `java` without a concrete path, hoping for `java` being in `PATH`.