# Get full command line from Java

Tags: java

How can I from within Java code find out which and how the running JVM was launched?
My code shall spawn another Java process hence I'd be especially interested in the first parameter - which usually (in C, Pascal, Bash, Python, ...) points to the currently running executable.

So when a Java application is run like

```
d:\openjdk\bin\java -Xmx500g -Dprop=name -jar my.jar param1 param2
```

I can access command line parameters in my main method like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main called with " + args);
    }
}
```

but that will deliver access to `param1` and `param2` only. How would I get the full command line?

Comment: Unless you have a process already running when the command line is executed, I doubt its possible to get that information

Comment: This is exactly what I am wondering about. So far I see no chance to get there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61860951/7109162

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958318/is-it-possible-to-get-the-command-used-to-launch-the-jvm-in-java contains more valid answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Determining location of JVM executable during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392416/determining-location-of-jvm-executable-during-runtime/61860951#61860951) I found the real answer to be:

```
ProcessHandle.current().info().commandLine().orElseThrow();
```

It returns the full command line as perceived by the operating system and thus contains all information: executable, options, main class, arguments, ...

Thank you, @XtremeBaumer

Comment: Please be precise: does this print ALL elements of the command line, or is it just sufficient to acquire the exact path to the JVM/java that was used?

Answer (score 1):

To get the command, use `ProcessHandle` adapted from your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72196870/16320675):

```java
String command = ProcessHandle
                 .current()
                 .info()
                 .command()
                 .orElse("<unable to determine command>"); // .orElseThrow()  to get Exception
```

---

Use the Runtime Management Bean `RuntimeMXBean` to obtain the **VM arguments** and the class path, like in:

```java
RuntimeMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
String classPath = mxBean.getClassPath();
List<String> inputArgs = mxBean.getInputArguments();
```

This will return all arguments passed to the virtual machine, **not** the parameters passed to the main method.

---

The code source can be get from the `ProtectionDomain` of the class.

Comment: I tested that one and it does not give the full command line - not even all the VM arguments.

Comment: very strange, works fine for me, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQq90.png) - but it sure does not return the full command line, as described in answer (and sorry that I do not provide full functional code to solve all your tasks)

Comment: Your screenshot does not show `java`, which could be different. And in my test also the classpath was missing. But the complete command line is what the question is targeting at.