# Writing On Text File C++

Tags: c++, loops, ofstream

I am simply trying to get a program to write "Test" to a created file. However, when I run the code below there is no file in the working directory. I am running this code on a Mac and compiling using gcc from Terminal.

```
    // writing on a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile ("example-1.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    if (myfile.fail())
       cout << "Fail" << endl;
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does anything get cout?

Comment: Please show the exact command you use to compile, and the exact command you use to execute.

Comment: Is the location writable ? What is the output of the program ?. How are you compiling and executing the program. Also it looks like you are using gcc which is GNU C compiler to compile a c++ program. For a c++ program use g++
g++ -g <compilationfile.c> -o <output file>

Comment: you may be better off checking `if (!myfile.good())` immediately after opening the file then `cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;` also you aren't opening the file in this case, you are checking to see if it is open, try `myfile.open()`. Another thing is to check file permissions

Comment: Ah sorry just realised your are opening the file using the constructor, perhaps add a try catch block to your file operations.

Comment: How are you running the program? Give full path to the file in the `ofstream` statement.

Comment: Do you have permission in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

All the code I posted is valid and works. However, I was compiling via the command line on  a Mac OSX using gcc. The command looks like this:

```
g++ -g nameofinputfile.cpp -o nameofoutput.out
```

This works fine, however when you open the .out file (compilation file) the example-1.txt file is created at the root of the Users file where Documents, Desktop, Downloads etc. exist. Simply you just have to state where it is to be created. [Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017034/c-where-does-the-ofstream-class-save-the-files-to) to learn how to specify the directory in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You must use of `fprintf()` for write text on text files.
For example :

```
fp1=fopen("report.txt","a+");
fprintf(fp1,"Port is open: %d\n\n",i);
fclose(fp1);
```

Comment: u can see more detail in [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)