# finding out the path to a file at runtime

Tags: c++, cmake

In a program I open a file say `file.dat` at runtime. The problem is when i run the executable it expects the file to be in the directory from where it is executed. I want the program to look into the same directory where the executable is present. What modifications should I make in my program (or in the build system).

For example consider this program:

```
int main()
{
std::ifstream ip("file.dat");
// do something.


return 0;
}
```

I am working on Ubuntu with g++-4.6 compiler and CMake build system. Since the project supports out-of-source build that means the program executable can be anywhere depending upon the directory where the `cmake` was invoked from.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

On many systems, the `argv[0]` parameter will have the path used to execute the program. Whether or not this is the full path of the program depends on how it was invoked.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string progname(argv[0]);
    std::string datafile;
    if (progname.find_last_of('/') != std::string::npos)
        datafile = progname.substr(0, progname.find_last_of('/')+1);
    datafile += "file.dat";
    std::ifstream ip(datafile.c_str());
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux reading /proc/self/exe is the best way to go.

```
  char app_path[1024];
  ssize_t len = ::readlink("/proc/self/exe", app_path, sizeof(app_path)-1);
  if (len != -1) {
    app_path[len] = '\0';
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
```

For other OS, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937/105015