# How to get executable path with getcwd when called from a symbolic link in C

Tags: c, linux, file-io, symlink

Say I have a program, `abc` in Linux, with a method:

```
char *currentPath(){
        char *path=NULL;
        path = getcwd(path, MAXPATHLEN);
        return path;
}
```

When calling `abc` directly, this path returns the path that `abc` is in.

If I make a symbolic link to `abc`, and call the symbolic link, `currentPath()` returns the path of the symbolic link.

Is there a way to get make this method return the path of `abc`? I am interested in accessing files relative to the location of `abc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `getcwd()` to help get the executable name; it is not a sensible way to go about finding the pathname of the executable.

On Linux, there is a symlink `/proc/self/exe` that gives you the name of the executable if you read it with the [`readlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) system call.  Beware, the `readlink()` system call does not null terminate the value it returns (and I have no idea why not; it is singularly weird behaviour in my book, and an instant cause of bugs for the unwary).

There are a number of problems with your scheme.

1. If the program is found via $PATH, there's no guarantee that the current directory is the same as the directory containing the executable.  If you think about it, you run `/bin/ls` without having to be in the `/bin` directory.
2. If you're worried about security, be aware that the value of `argv[0]` is under the control of the program launching the target program.  The shell behaves nicely; other programs may be more malicious:

   ```
   #include <unistd.h>
   int main(void)
   {
       char *argv[] = { "/opt/you/bin/bogus", "300", 0 };
       execvp("sleep", argv);
       return(-1);
   }
   ```

   This passes the program name as `/opt/you/bin/bogus` even though it invokes the program `sleep`.

If you search the web, you will find plenty of examples of 'how to get the executable name' that assume that `argv[0]` is the way to go; it is not.  Other platforms have other techniques for getting to the executable name.  Using `/proc/self/exe` is not portable; neither are the other techniques.

Comment: @JohnathanLeffler Thank you very much for explaining this.  I think it makes the most sense to follow readlink based on your reply.  In my situation I am currently only supporting linux, but will expand to other platforms.  Based on the anwswer in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937/618775 it looks like I will need expand this particular requirement to have different implementations for each platform.  I think that is okay.  Again, thanks for helping a C#/Java developer making an extremely awkward entry back into the world of C.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`realpath(const char *path, char *resolved_path)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/realpath.3.html)

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./, /../ and
>          extra '/' characters in the null-terminated string named by path to produce a
>          canonicalized absolute pathname.

In your case:

```
char *currentPath() {
  char *path, *canon_path;
  path = getcwd(NULL, MAXPATHLEN);
  canon_path = realpath(path, NULL);
  free(path);
  return canon_path;
}
```

Note that this does not get the path of the executable program (it is unclear what you're trying to do). To do that portably is trickier. You'll need to use the value of `argv[0]` to get it:

```
char *bindir(char *argv0) {
  char *canon_path = realpath(argv0, NULL);
  char *canon_dir = strdup(dirname(canon_path));
  free(canon_path);
  return canon_dir;
}
```

The `strdup` call is required because `dirname` may modify its argument and return a pointer into that or return a pointer to a statically allocated buffer.

Comment: The current directory is not germane to finding the path name of the executable.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This works for the most part, until the executable is launched from PATH.  In this case, realpath does not work.  Your explanation is clear though, and does solve the symlink issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (modify it to meet your need):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAXPATHLEN      256

char buffer[1024];

char *currentPath(char *bin_path){
        char *path = NULL;
        ssize_t len;
        struct stat file_stat;

        if (lstat(bin_path, &file_stat) != 0) 
        {
                /* handle error */
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
        }

        if (!S_ISREG(file_stat.st_mode)) 
        {
                /* file is a symlink */
                fprintf(stdout, "Is a symlink\n");
                if ((len = readlink(bin_path, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) != -1)
                        buffer[len] = '\0';
                /* In this case we return the name of the link */
                return buffer;
        }
        else
        {
                fprintf(stdout, "Is a regular file\n");
                path = getcwd(bin_path, MAXPATHLEN);

                return path;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        fprintf(stdout, "My path is : %s\n", currentPath(argv[0]));

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the first symlink points to a second one? The use of `path = getcwd(bin_path, MAXPATHLEN);` is a little odd, too (for multiple reasons).  And, despite the question discussing it, the current working directory has essentially nothing to do with the location of the executable.