# What is the equivalent of /proc/self/exe on Macintosh OS X Mavericks?

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, porting, c++03, darwin

I'm porting a Linux C++03 application to Darwin OS X and have some code that reads the symbolic link at /proc/self/exe to determine the directory in which the executable running is located.

How can I compute the directory of the current executable running on Macintosh Darwin OS X Mavericks in C++?

Here is my existing code that works on Linux:

```
bool
resolveBinaryLocation(string &binaryDirname)
{
  // Read the symbolic link '/proc/self/exe'.
  const char *linkName = "/proc/self/exe";
  const size_t bufSize = PATH_MAX + 1;
  char dirNameBuffer[bufSize];
  const int ret = int(readlink(linkName, dirNameBuffer, bufSize - 1));

  if (ret == -1) {
    // Permission denied (We must be inetd with this app run as other than root).
    return false;
  }

  dirNameBuffer[ret] = 0; // Terminate the string with a NULL character.

  binaryDirname = dirNameBuffer;

  // Erase the name of the executable:
  string::size_type last = binaryDirname.size() - 1;
  string::size_type idx  = binaryDirname.rfind(DSI_PATH_CHAR, last);

  // Add one to keep the trailing directory separator.
  binaryDirname.erase(idx + 1);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you setting up an app with a bundle or is it a CLI exe?

Comment: Your question is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe

Comment: @RhythmicFistman It is a CLI exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I settled upon as a solution:

```
bool
resolveBinaryLocation(string &binaryDirname)
{
  const size_t bufSize = PATH_MAX + 1;
  char dirNameBuffer[bufSize];

#ifdef __APPLE__
  uint32_t size = bufSize;

  if (_NSGetExecutablePath(dirNameBuffer, &size) != 0) {
    // Buffer size is too small.
    return false;
  }
#else // not __APPLE__
  // Read the symbolic link '/proc/self/exe'.
  const char *linkName = "/proc/self/exe";
  const int ret = int(readlink(linkName, dirNameBuffer, bufSize - 1));

  if (ret == -1) {
    // Permission denied (We must be inetd with this app run as other than root).
    return false;
  }
    
  dirNameBuffer[ret] = 0; // Terminate the string with a NULL character.
#endif // else not __APPLE__

  binaryDirname = dirNameBuffer;

  // Erase the name of the executable:
  string::size_type last = binaryDirname.size() - 1;
  string::size_type idx  = binaryDirname.rfind(DSI_PATH_CHAR, last);

  // Add one to keep the trailing directory separator.
  binaryDirname.erase(idx + 1);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the non-standard `#ifdef ARCH_darwin_14_i86`, it would be better to just use the standard `#ifdef __APPLE__`

Comment: @SimonKissane Updated.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth pointing out that `/proc/self/exe` and `_NSGetExecutablePath` are non-equivalent. If the executable is deleted or replaced while running, opening `/proc/self/exe` will still open the running version of the executable, while opening `_NSGetExecutablePath` will either fail (if deleted) or open the new version instead

If it is important to get a macOS equivalent to `/proc/self/exe` which works even when the executable is deleted/replaced, one option is to open an FD to `_NSGetExecutablePath` during startup and keep it open. Suppose that FD is 3, then `/dev/fd/3` will behave *mostly* like Linux `/proc/self/exe`, including the same behaviour when the executable is deleted/replaced. (One difference is you can self-exec using `/proc/self/exe` on Linux, whereas macOS lacks `fexecve` and [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74538771/2147204) won't let you exec anything in `/dev/fd`.)

Theoretically, there is a possibility for a race condition here: between starting and opening itself, the executable could be replaced by a new version or deleted. One might decide that such a race condition is so rare there is no need to worry about it; but if one wants to handle it, I have two suggestions:

- If at startup, opening the path returned by `_NSGetExecutablePath()` fails (the executable has been deleted while starting, or some other odd condition) – just abort with an error message
- Check the `LC_UUID` of the executable you open is the same as your own – abort with an error message if they are different (means the executable replaced with new version at startup race condition has occurred). If aborting isn't an option, you could try to exec the new version instead.