# Application thinks it's in my home folder OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos

I compile using eclipse and c++11 under both Windows and OSX.  When I create a release and drag it to another folder, the Windows binary has the current current working directory.  The OSX release thinks it's in my home folder.  No matter where I place it, it thinks it is running in my home directory.

I put a print statement in my code to prove it:
Current working dir: /Users/Dom

This problem only occurs if I double click the binary.  If I open a terminal and run the program using ./ it opens in the proper directory.

I'm not sure how to fix this, but it needs to be fixed in order for the application to find relative path specific resources.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

```
char path[1024];
uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) == 0){ /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work under Windows if you're UAC-elevated either, as the current directory is reset to `%WINDIR%\system32` during the elevation. All processes [on these platforms] have the concept of a current directory which is NOT guaranteed to be the program's directory. You'll likely need to find your binary in another way, such as one of these ways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937/2101267