# C, file, and path, and things

Tags: c, file

I have a C application that does this features:

- being called by an Internet protocol (syntax: gett:test!test123!456 ).
- reads a file and parse it (the file will be exactly on the same folder as the exe and name is defined.
- parses the syntax I wrote previously (takes test!test123!456 as argv) and parse it
- calls another application with the parsed arguments (from above)

I have successfuly make the features. Otherwise, the only problem (currently) is:
when I call the application from another location or application (e.g cmd), the application seems to be losing the file defined above.
the exception handler for this, in my code is:

```
    /// open the config.txt module
FILE *f;
f=fopen("configgg.txt", "r");

if (f == 0) { /* If opening failed */
    MessageBox(NULL, "Failed in opening file. Make sure you have the config.txt", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return -1;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Sorry for the broken language.
Thank you in advance, I appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: `fopen("configgg.txt", "r")` is looking for the file in whatever folder you are executing from. You'll need to include the path to the file.

Comment: That's it. the file is supposed to be on the same folder as the application is. but, I don't understand how do I fix the definition. also, this application may be placed in different folders. that leads to the variable location, not 100% path static.

Comment: If the config file is always with the executable, then you'll need to programmatically [get the path of the executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937), then use that same path for the config file. Just to test things out, you could hard-code the paths, but in the long run, you probably want to do it programmatically to avoid issues later.

Comment: You should check `argv[0]`, it should have the path to your executable, just trim what come after the last `/` or `\\`, and add your file name.

Comment: Okay, I have checked `argv[0]` and I managed to have `GetModuleFileName` working. both gives me a directory and the exe name. now, how should I trim it? (currently, I parse, cut, and store everything into char arrays (using `strtok`). later on, I use `strcat` to combine them. is there any better solution for this? thanks

Comment: I don t think so. String manipulation in C are limited...

Comment: okay, so I will be using the method I am using. I'll try.

Comment: At stack-overflow, accept an answer to show the problem is solved.  Do not change the title to "(solved)".  Please undo the edit and accept an answer (posting your own if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

As is, you call a relative path to the path the user is in. You should make the path relative to your application.

You can get the full path to your application via `argv[0]`, you can then trim the end and concatene to the name of your config file to get the full path of your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have finally solved this problem. Solution:

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
char *s = strtok(buffer, ":\\");
char *d[250];
int i=0;
int j=0;

while(s!=NULL){
    d[i]=s;
    s = strtok(NULL, ":\\");
    i++;
    j++;
}

for (i=0; i<j; i++){
    printf("d[%d]: %s\n", i, d[i]);
}
j--;
char theloc[250]="";

for (i=0; i<j; i++){
    strcat(theloc,d[i]);
    if (i==0) {
        strcat(theloc, ":\\");
    } else if (i==j-1){
        strcat(theloc, "\\");
    } else {
    strcat(theloc, "\\");
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for the help, @lurker @DrakaSAN
(as well as the minus vote. I know this question is stupid yet worthless)