# C/C++ argv memory manage

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

A standard C/C++ program format.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}
```

I wonder how `argv` data is arranged in memory when `main` is called. I got this function [copy_argv()](https://github.com/gitchs/node/blob/v0.10.30-leon-custome/src/node.cc#L3017) from Node.js repo. It works as if memory is arranged this way:

```
argv_area|NULL|argv_data_area
```

Does OS really handle `argv`'s memory in this way?

As far as this is OS dependet, just discuss about Linux 64bit

Comment: There's no specification about how the various strings pointed to by the elements in the `argv` array will be arranged.  I think it's likely that they'll be contiguous, but it would be perfectly valid for them to be scattered all over the place.  Also, their memory allocation doesn't have to directly follow the `argv` array allocation.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by the nodejs way to copy them. I'd generally use one malloc for char** then one for each char*. Are they doing this for performance issues ?

Comment: @Logar: Yes, they're trying to minimize the number of calls to `malloc`, which saves both time and space. Whether it's worthwhile depends on the platform.

Comment: @Logar, I suppose that may be some reused code of pedigree, written at times when calling `malloc` was considered expensive, so the code made some extra effort to avoid extra calls. Perhaps, there's no need to be that frugal nowadays, but if you already have frugal code, why not reuse it.

Comment: I edited the question a bit, since it was hard for me to understand what you were actually asking, and it seemed to depend on the external link. Please roll-back or edit further, if I misunderstood.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Why not make your comment an (the) answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original `argv` is normally handled as a single contiguous block of `char *` values, followed immediately by another block of `char *` values for the environment (the `envp` in the `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` variant of `main()`, also pointed to by `environ`).  These are then followed by the argument strings and environment strings themselves.

The argument list and environment are probably not created by `malloc()` per se — the arguments and environment are set up by the `execve()` system call.

At one point three years ago, I was playing with 'find `argv[0]` from a function other than main' and wrote the code shown below.  It still works on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.4 — the original tested version was Snow Leopard 10.6) and Ubuntu 14.04.  (There are better, but platform specific, ways to get `argv[0]` from a function, but that's a [separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe), so I would not use this technique, but it does work on some common platforms.)

```
#include "posixver.h"
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* putenv(), setenv() */

extern char **environ;  /* Should be declared in <unistd.h> */

/*
** The object of the exercise is: given just environ (since that is all
** that is available to a library function) attempt to find argv[0] (and
** hence argc).
**
** On some platforms, the layout of memory is such that the number of
** arguments (argc) is available, followed by the argument vector,
** followed by the environment vector.
**
**          argv                            environ
**            |                                |
**            v                                v
** | argc | argv0 | argv1 | ... | argvN | 0 | env0 | env1 | ... | envN | 0 |
**
** This applies to:
** -- Solaris 10 (32-bit, 64-bit SPARC)
** -- MacOS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard, 32-bit and 64-bit)
** -- Linux (RHEL 5 on x86/64, 32-bit and 64-bit)
**
** Sadly, this is not quite what happens on the other two Unix
** platforms.  The value preceding argv0 seems to be a 0.
** -- AIX 6.1          (32-bit, 64-bit)
** -- HP-UX 11.23 IA64 (32-bit, 64-bit)
**       Sub-standard POSIX support (no setenv()) and C99 support (no %zd).
**
** NB: If putenv() or setenv() is called to add an environment variable,
** then the base address of environ changes radically, moving off the
** stack onto heap, and all bets are off.  Modifying an existing
** variable is not a problem.
**
** Spotting the change from stack to heap is done by observing whether
** the address pointed to by environ is more than 128 K times the size
** of a pointer from the address of a local variable.
**
** This code is nominally incredibly machine-specific - but actually
** works remarkably portably.
*/

typedef struct Arguments
{
    char   **argv;
    size_t   argc;
} Arguments;

static void print_cpp(const char *tag, int i, char **ptr)
{
    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)ptr;
    printf("%s[%d] = 0x%" PRIXPTR " (0x%" PRIXPTR ") (%s)\n",
            tag, i, p, (uintptr_t)(*ptr), (*ptr == 0 ? "<null>" : *ptr));
}

enum { MAX_DELTA = sizeof(void *) * 128 * 1024 };

static Arguments find_argv0(void)
{
    static char *dummy[] = { "<unknown>", 0 };
    Arguments args;
    uintptr_t i;
    char **base = environ - 1;
    uintptr_t delta = ((uintptr_t)&base > (uintptr_t)environ) ? (uintptr_t)&base - (uintptr_t)environ : (uintptr_t)environ - (uintptr_t)&base;
    if (delta < MAX_DELTA)
    {
        for (i = 2; (uintptr_t)(*(environ - i) + 2) != i && (uintptr_t)(*(environ - i)) != 0; i++)
            print_cpp("test", i, environ-i);
        args.argc = i - 2;
        args.argv = environ - i + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        args.argc = 1;
        args.argv = dummy;
    }

    printf("argc    = %zd\n", args.argc);
    for (i = 0; i <= args.argc; i++)
        print_cpp("argv", i, &args.argv[i]);

    return args;
}

static void print_arguments(void)
{
    Arguments args = find_argv0();
    printf("Command name and arguments\n");
    printf("argc    = %zd\n", args.argc);
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= args.argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%zd] = %s\n", i, (args.argv[i] ? args.argv[i] : "<null>"));
}

static int check_environ(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t n = argc;
    size_t i;
    unsigned long delta = (argv > environ) ? argv - environ : environ - argv;
    printf("environ = 0x%lX; argv = 0x%lX (delta: 0x%lX)\n", (unsigned long)environ, (unsigned long)argv, delta);
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        print_cpp("chkv", i, &argv[i]);
    if (delta > (unsigned long)argc + 1)
        return 0;

    for (i = 1; i < n + 2; i++)
    {
        printf("chkr[%zd] = 0x%lX (0x%lX) (%s)\n", i, (unsigned long)(environ - i), (unsigned long)(*(environ - i)),
                (*(environ-i) ? *(environ-i) : "<null>"));
        fflush(0);
    }
    i = n + 2;
    printf("chkF[%zd] = 0x%lX (0x%lX)\n", i, (unsigned long)(environ - i), (unsigned long)(*(environ - i)));
    i = n + 3;
    printf("chkF[%zd] = 0x%lX (0x%lX)\n", i, (unsigned long)(environ - i), (unsigned long)(*(environ - i)));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Before setting environment\n");
    if (check_environ(argc, argv))
        print_arguments();

    //putenv("TZ=US/Pacific");
    setenv("SHELL", "/bin/csh", 1);

    printf("After modifying environment\n");
    if (check_environ(argc, argv) == 0)
        printf("Modifying environment messed everything up\n");
    print_arguments();

    putenv("CODSWALLOP=nonsense");

    printf("After adding to environment\n");
    if (check_environ(argc, argv) == 0)
        printf("Adding environment messed everything up\n");
    print_arguments();

    return 0;
}
```

Example output from Mac OS X:

```
Before setting environment
environ = 0x7FFF584D04C8; argv = 0x7FFF584D0498 (delta: 0x6)
chkv[0] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
chkv[1] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
chkv[2] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
chkv[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
chkv[4] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
chkv[5] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
chkr[1] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
chkr[2] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
chkr[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
chkr[4] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
chkr[5] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
chkr[6] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
chkF[7] = 0x7FFF584D0490 (0x5)
chkF[8] = 0x7FFF584D0488 (0x0)
test[2] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
test[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
test[4] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
test[5] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
test[6] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
argc    = 5
argv[0] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
argv[1] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
argv[2] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
argv[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
argv[4] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
argv[5] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
Command name and arguments
argc    = 5
argv[0] = ./find_argv0
argv[1] = macedonian
argv[2] = obelisk
argv[3] = mental breakdown
argv[4] = testing: 1, 2, 3
argv[5] = <null>
After modifying environment
environ = 0x7FFF584D04C8; argv = 0x7FFF584D0498 (delta: 0x6)
chkv[0] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
chkv[1] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
chkv[2] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
chkv[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
chkv[4] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
chkv[5] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
chkr[1] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
chkr[2] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
chkr[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
chkr[4] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
chkr[5] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
chkr[6] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
chkF[7] = 0x7FFF584D0490 (0x5)
chkF[8] = 0x7FFF584D0488 (0x0)
test[2] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
test[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
test[4] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
test[5] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
test[6] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
argc    = 5
argv[0] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
argv[1] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
argv[2] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
argv[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
argv[4] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
argv[5] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
Command name and arguments
argc    = 5
argv[0] = ./find_argv0
argv[1] = macedonian
argv[2] = obelisk
argv[3] = mental breakdown
argv[4] = testing: 1, 2, 3
argv[5] = <null>
After adding to environment
environ = 0x7FB1EA403B60; argv = 0x7FFF584D0498 (delta: 0x9ADC19927)
chkv[0] = 0x7FFF584D0498 (0x7FFF584D06B0) (./find_argv0)
chkv[1] = 0x7FFF584D04A0 (0x7FFF584D06BD) (macedonian)
chkv[2] = 0x7FFF584D04A8 (0x7FFF584D06C8) (obelisk)
chkv[3] = 0x7FFF584D04B0 (0x7FFF584D06D0) (mental breakdown)
chkv[4] = 0x7FFF584D04B8 (0x7FFF584D06E1) (testing: 1, 2, 3)
chkv[5] = 0x7FFF584D04C0 (0x0) (<null>)
Adding environment messed everything up
argc    = 1
argv[0] = 0x107730040 (0x10772FEC0) (<unknown>)
argv[1] = 0x107730048 (0x0) (<null>)
Command name and arguments
argc    = 1
argv[0] = <unknown>
argv[1] = <null>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you linked in Node.js does not in fact assume anything about the layout of argv and its referents.  Instead, the layout you mentioned is the **output** format of the function.  It does in fact create an array like  you say, but it does not require the input to be arranged like that (if it did, it could just do a single `memcpy()`).

In other words, the special layout you describe is sufficient, but not necessary, for any program's argv.

Why does Node do this?  It's right there in the comments:

```
  // Logic to duplicate argv as Init() modifies arguments
  // that are passed into it.
  char **argv_copy = copy_argv(argc, argv);

  // This needs to run *before* V8::Initialize()
  // Use copy here as to not modify the original argv:
  Init(argc, argv_copy);
```

And why is that?  Because `Init()` calls `parseArgs()` which strips out the few options it understands from argv, leaving the rest to be processed elsewhere.  It seems a bit roundabout to me, but the whole purpose of the argv copying routine you found is just to have something that the program **can** use as argv, rather than there being any specific requirement for the exact layout they use.  It is a simple layout though, and requires just a single `free()` later.