# Get the path to the bundle in Mono C# CLI application

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, path, mono

I need to retrieve the full path (up to directory) of the application's executable file made using `mkbundle --static`. It is a CLI application that I test on OSX, suppose the executable resides at `/usr/local/bin/`.

The matters *might* be further complicated (but I don't really know) since I want to run the utility from any directory, so I add the above path to `$PATH` environment variable (in this case, it is  already there).

Now, suppose the application is launched while being at `~/dir1/dir2/`, and suppose it prints the `Application.StartupPath`. That yields the path `~/dir1/dir2/`. In contrast, I want to always retrieve the *real* directory from which the application is launched, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/`.

Is there any way to achieve this (preferably in a platform-independent way)?

I use Xamarin Studio configured with Mono/.NET 4.5 and C# 6.0.

**UPDATE:** Getting `typeof(Program).Assembly.Location` also doesn't help much.

I mean, it works well when I just run the normal application executable (produced during the build process).

However, if I run a bundle made with `mkbundle --static`, the `Location` just gives the executable name `App.exe` without any prior path.

Probably it just displays the relative path inside the bundle. Is there any way I can get the path to the bundle itself?..

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I've found reliable (probably not the fastest way though) is through `Process`:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a type defined in an assembly that is part of your application you can find its location by doing:

```
string location = typeof(Foo).Assembly.Location;
```

This gives you the full path to the .dll or .exe, depending on where the type Foo is defined. Then you can use Path.GetDirectoryName if you only want the directory.

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
```

The above should work with Mono and also on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It works if I run `mono app.exe`, but not when I run a bundle created with `mkbundle --static`. In this case, it just displays `app.exe`, perhaps it is the path relative to the bundle?..

Still can't figure out how to get the path to the bundle, or if it is possible at all.

Comment: I changed the question body to reflect the new understanding of the problem. Do you know anything that could be helpful in my situation?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I suspect you will have to use a [native api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe) to find the path to the current executable.