# Accessing Local Application Files In CLI Enviroment?

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-platform

I'm not sure how to ask this, but I'll do my best. Anyway, my situation is this: I have files that I want my app/executable to be able to access at all times that are relative to the executable's path or in the same directory as the program. Since I want my program to be able to run in any CWD and still get everything it needs. I want to know what's the best way or method to get a file that's relative to my executable, that won't mess up the user's CWD?

The approach I had in my head is this:

1. Get program's directory using OS dependent function.
2. Use some string manipulation to get the program's home directory.
3. Append to the string the file I require during run time without having to use any hat trick CWD commands.

Not sure if Windows/Linux already has something up it's sleeves to deal with this, but I thought I should know if there is a better alternative.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe

Comment: That's what I thought, wasn't sure if there was an alternative way.

Answer (score -1):

If the files, that you want to access from your C binary, are in the same directory or subdirectory, you can access directly by using ".", this is the current directory.

or you can simply use the getwd function.

```
char *getwd(char *buf);
```

Typically, you can use like this (this snippet will print you, the current directory of the C binary):

```
int main()
{       
 char buf[4096];
 getwd(buf);
 printf(but);
}
```

Comment: But what if my binary is being called outside of the directory of where the binary is being stored in terminal? i.e app being stored in /etc/bin/, but it's being executed in the user's home folder. How would I fetch a config file or something that's in the app's folder?