# Python - importing c++ module interfaces - cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm using folder structure like this:

```
program
program/app/app.py
program/app/lib.so
program/app/py_interfaces.so
program/launcher.py
```

I have compiled python interfaces `py_interaces.so` with boost.python linking to `./lib.so`, so it would load library from the same folder as interfaces.
I'm importing interfaces in `app.py`:

```
import py_interfaces
```

and if I run `app.py` it works fine. But I need to run from `launcher/py` and when I do that, I get error:

```
Import Error: ./lib.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.
```

I guess it loads `py_interfaces.so` fine, but it searches for `lib.so` in wrong folder: `program`. Would it be possible to force it to do it correctly? Should I link differently? I dont' want to change working directory (I need other files from root `program` directory)

Comment: I gave the general answer, but without more code as in what's in your `PYTHONPATH` and the code from `py_interfaces` referencing `lib` I can't help more.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rpath+origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `.` is the directory you're expecting? Note `.` means current **working** directory. `launcher.py` is not in the same directory as `lib.so`, and so that's what you're seeing. The way you linked things, you have to work in the app dir.

Try using real paths when linking or the path relative to the library, `py_interfaces.so`. This is something you need to fix in `py_interfaces` itself.

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe) is a SO post about referencing a file relative to the executable/library path.

As mentioned by N.M. n the comments, the correct way to link with a relative path is to provide `-rpath` with `$ORIGIN` when linking, making the whole dependency thing more robust.

Comment: What I want is for `py_interfaces.so` to always look for `lib.so` in the same directory. And it works fine, excluding my scenario.

Comment: Works fine you mean only when running from the same directory?

Comment: Yes. But in my case I want `Launcher.py` to start `app/app.py` in another process. But then I think app.py imports `py_interfaces.so` "correctly", from `app` dir, but then interfaces search for `lib.so` in root folder.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. `./lib.so` means library will be looked for in current working directory, not "the same" directory as I thought. So it runs fine when working directory is script directory, but if it's not, problems occurs. The right way was provided by @n.m. - it it to use `-rpath` option with `$ORIGIN` setting. I tested it and it works I as wanted. Than you. Post it as an answer please so I can accept it.

Comment: @Pawel thanks, I should write the answer explicitly - thanks and done.