# Size of an executable at runtime in C/C++ on Linux without /proc/self/exe?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I need to get the size of a C/C++ executable at runtime in code. Unfortunately I  cannot use /proc/self/exe as it's restricted on the target system.

Comment: Isnt the exe path given in the first argument to main? Can you get size from there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe?rq=1 may help

Comment: Does [`dl_iterate_phdr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) help?

Comment: From experimenting, casting `info->dlpi_addr` to `ElfW(Ehdr)*` and calculating the end of the section headers is usually the end of the file. Of course, it's not *guaranteed* that section headers will be the last meaningful thing in the file, and there could always be some trailing junk ...

Comment: dl_iterate_phdr seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dl_iterate_phdr

https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr

This solved it! Thanks @o11c!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's a lot simpler than my attempt in the comments. The executable is simply:

```
(const char *)getauxval(AT_EXECFN)
```

That said, you should always try to open `/proc/self/exe` first since the executable may have been deleted/moved/replaced while running.

Answer (score 0):

First string in `argv` should be path used to run the executable. You can use `std::filesystem::file_size` to get the size.

In an exceptional case, where the command is a plain basename without a path separator, you need to search for it from the directories in the `$PATH` env variable.