# How to make a program work regardless of the user's pwd when using file streams?

Tags: c++, directory, fstream, ostream

Consider project in `~/my/computer/my_project` with files:

- main.cpp
- input

We want the project to be usable on `~/your/computer` so we use relative paths when dealing with file streams:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main ()
{
    std::ifstream stream("input");
    
    if (!stream.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "No file detected" << std::endl;
    }
    
    stream.close();
}
```

This works when the user executes the program in the `my_project` directory, but fails otherwise (prints `No file detected`, which isn't desired).

How to make a program work regardless of the user's present working directory when using file streams like this?

Comment: `std::ifstream stream("/the/path/to/my/computer/my_project/input");` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I said in the question that `We want the project to be usable on ~/your/computer so we use relative paths`

Comment: The absolute path will also be usable in that path. The best usual solution is to pass the path as an argument - that way, user can use any path he desires.

Comment: @KamilCuk, sorry, I don't understand your answer? How would one pass in the path as an argument? Surely not by requesting the user to do that? Or do you mean using, say, a `Makefile` command to pass it in?

Comment: Just like `cd /dir` you would do `./your_program /dir`. `Surely not by requesting the user to do that?` Specifically by requesting the user to do that, just like `cd` does - request user to put path as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a relative path from the location of your executable file.

This depends on the OS, and here are a few ways to do that:
[Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe)